# What is the difference between .Equals and ==

Tags: c#, .net, string

What is the difference between `a.Equals(b)` and `a == b` for value types, reference types, and strings? It would seem as though a == b works just fine for strings, but I'm trying to be sure to use good coding practices.

Comment: Have a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144530/-or-equals

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [**When should I use Equals and when should I use ==**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals/):

> The Equals method is just a virtual
>   one defined in System.Object, and
>   overridden by whichever classes choose
>   to do so. The == operator is an
>   operator which can be overloaded by
>   classes, but which usually has
>   identity behaviour.
>
> For reference types where == has not
>   been overloaded, it compares whether
>   two references refer to the same
>   object - which is exactly what the
>   implementation of Equals does in
>   System.Object.
>
> Value types do not provide an overload
>   for == by default. However, most of
>   the value types provided by the
>   framework provide their own overload.
>   The default implementation of Equals
>   for a value type is provided by
>   ValueType, and uses reflection to make
>   the comparison, which makes it
>   significantly slower than a
>   type-specific implementation normally
>   would be. This implementation also
>   calls Equals on pairs of references
>   within the two values being compared.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create two equal but distinct strings
        string a = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
        string b = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});

        Console.WriteLine (a==b);
        Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b));

        // Now let's see what happens with the same tests but
        // with variables of type object
        object c = a;
        object d = b;

        Console.WriteLine (c==d);
        Console.WriteLine (c.Equals(d));
    }
}
```

The result of this short sample program is

```
True
True
False
True
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think line with Console.WriteLine (c.Equals(d)); here is misleading, because for reference types Equals will compare values of references, what is important. And here it is True only because in runtime variable "b" contains string instance, and String overrides virtual Equals(object d) method, and its logic contain comparison of strings exact values char by char. In this scenario it will be really same strings values of "hello", but in case of different strings in will lead to False in result of Equals method.

Answer (score 12):

[Here is a great blog post about *WHY* the implementations are different](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx).

Essentially == is going to be bound at compile time using the types of the variables and .Equals is going to be dynamically bound at runtime.

Comment: +1 for the Lippert link, I was looking for this earlier!

Answer (score 11):

In the most shorthand answer:

**== opertator is to check identity.** (i.e: a==b are these two are the same object?)

**.Equals() is to check value.** (i.e: a.Equals(b) are both holding identical values?)

**With one exception:** 

For **string** and **predefined value types** (such as **int**, **float** etc..),
the operator == will answer for value and not identity. (same as using .Equals())

Answer (score 8):

One significant difference between them is that `==` is a static binary operator that works on two instances of a type whereas `Equals` is an instance method.  The reason this matters is that you can do this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
Foo foo2 = null;
foo2 == foo;
```

But you cannot do this without throwing a `NullReferenceException`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
Foo foo2 = null;
foo2.Equals(foo);
```

Comment: I found out `Object.Equals(x,y)` wont give `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 7):

At a simple level, the difference is which method is called.  The == method will attempt ot bind to operator== if defined for the types in question.  If no == is found for value types it will do a value comparison and for reference types it will do a reference comparison.  A .Equals call will do a virtual dispatch on the .Equals method.

As to what the particular methods do, it's all in the code.  Users can define / override these methods and do anything they please.  Ideally this methods should be equivalent (sorry for the pun) and have the same output but it is not always the case.

Comment: +1 Good to mention that Equals is a virtual method.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to help remember the difference is that `a.Equals(b)` is more analogous to
 `a == (object)b`.

The `.Equals()` method is not generic and accepts an argument of type "object", and so when comparing to the == operator you have to think about it as if the right-hand operand were cast to object first.

One implication is that `a.Equals(b)` will nearly always return some value for `a` and `b`, regardless of type (the normal way to overload is to just return `false` if `b` is an unkown type).  `a == b` will just throw an exception if there's no comparison available for those types.

Answer (score 0):

"`==`" is an operator that can be overloaded to perform different things based on the types being compared.

The default operation performed by "`==`" is `a.Equals(b);`

Here's how you could overload this operator for string types:

```
public static bool operator == (string str1, string str2) 
{
    return (str1.Length == str2.Length;)
}
```

Note that this is different than `str1.Equals(str2);`

Derived classes can also override and redefine `Equals()`.

As far as "best practices" go, it depends on your intent.

Comment: Could you clarify what yo mean by "The default operation performed by "==" is a.Equals(b)".

Comment: If you don't overload the '==' operator, it does the same thing as the Equals() function does. For strings, it does a string comparison, for user types it compares references.

Answer (score 0):

For strings you want to be careful of culture specific comparisons. The classic example is the german double S, that looks a bit like a b. This should match with "ss" but doesn't in a simple == comparison.

For string comparisons that are culture sensitive use: String.Compare(expected, value, StringComparison....) == 0 ? with the StringComparison overload you need.

Answer (score 0):

By default, both `==` and `.Equals()` are equivalent apart from the possibility of calling `.Equals()` on a `null` instance (which would give you a `NullReferenceException`). You can, however, override the functionality of either of them independently (though I'm not sure that would ever be a good idea unless you're trying to work around the shortcomings of another system), which would mean you could MAKE them different.

You'll find people on both sides of the aisle as to the one to use. I prefer the operator rather than the function.

If you're talking about strings, though, it's likely a better idea to use `string.Compare()` instead of either one of those options.