# Java/Android Programming / EditText -> getText().toString()

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [why equals() method when we have == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)

All I'm trying to do here is to compare a text that was entered in a text-field widget with a given string ("abc") and then set the button-text to either "wrong pass" or "pass ok". However, the button-text is always set to "wrong pass" even if I enter the correct "password". What am I doing wrong?

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText textedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textedit);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (textedit.getText().toString() == "abc") 
                button.setText("pass ok"); // doesn't work
            else 
                button.setText("wrong pass");

        }
    });
}

...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

one issue is:

```
if (textedit.getText().toString() == "abc")
```

should be

```
if (textedit.getText().toString().equals("abc") )
```

even better:

```
 if ("abc".equals(textedit.getText().toString()))
```

It is always better to use `equals()` while comparing String/Objects instead of using `==`

`==` checks for reference equality. `equals()` check for content equality.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have a lot to learn ;)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare String in Java / Android with `==`, you must use `equals()`:

```
if (textedit.getText().toString().equals("abc"))
```

You can find a good explanation of *why* in: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661)

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this, using "equals".

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText getpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textedit);

            String pass = getpass.getText().toString();

            if(pass.equals("abc")){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();



            }else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I also know what a Toast is :)