# While loop in Java, string comparison does not work

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I'm working on a small program that asks for your name using a `Scanner`.  If you enter blankstring, then I would like the console to display a message.

Here's what I tried doing:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Adventure
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {      
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner (System.in);                             
        System.out.println("What's your name?");                                 
        String name = myScan.nextLine();

        while (!(name == ""))   //Always returns false.
        {
            System.out.println("That's not your name. Please try again.");
            name = myScan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("It's a pleasure to meet you, " + name + ".");
    }
}
```

The code never enters the while loop.  Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to provide a description of the problem you are having so others don't have to guess.

Comment: -1 (This can be undone) Please write a useful title and describe the problem. In this case, look up `[java] string not equal` in the SO search for *many, many* duplicate questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your condition to:

```
while(!name.equals("")) {
```

or as suggested below by *m0skit0*:

```
while(!name.isEmpty()) {
```

## See also

- [why equals() method when we have == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763)

Comment: Or even better, `!name.isEmpty()` (only Java 6+ ofc).

Comment: @m0skit0: thanks, I took the liberty to incorporate your comment into an answer. Hope you don't mind (?) And BTW [Java 6 will no longer be maintained](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) in less than a month.

Comment: Of course not, +1 for asking :)