# How come readLine() is not blocking?

Tags: java

Given the following code, the first call to readLine() is not blocking, both "Enter name:" and "Enter address:" are printed at the same time, and address gets assigned to whatever is entered. Why? I've tried putting them in separate try blocks, getting rid of the loop and generally reordering things.

```
public class AddressReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Path file = Paths.get("d:/java IO/addresses.txt");

    try {
        Files.createDirectories(file.getParent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error craeting directory: " + file.getParent());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int c = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("<a>dd an entry or <r>ead entries");
        c = br.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occured, try again");
    }
    switch (c) {
    case 'a':
        String name = null;
        String address = null;

        while (name == null || name == "" || address == null || address == "") {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter name:");
                name = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Enter address:");
                address = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error has occured, try again");
            }
            System.out.println("name = " + name);
            System.out.println("address = " + address);
        }
        //writeEntry(file, name, address);
        break;
    case 'r':
        //readEntries(file);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: your string equality check is wrong. you should use equals() method, not == operator

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832

Comment: you're right about the string check, but thats not whats causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of this line:

```
c = br.read();
```

This does not consume the new-line character that is produced by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

To solve this issue, use this instead:

```
c = br.readLine().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Over and above whats already been said, for what you're trying to do I suggest using the Console instead:

```
Console console = System.console();
String name = console.readLine("Create a name.");
char[] password = console.readPassword("Create a password.");
System.out.println(name + ":" + new String(password));
```