# Boolean.TRUE == myBoolean vs. Boolean.TRUE.equals(myBoolean)

Tags: java, object, boolean, equals, equality

Is there ever a situation where using `equals(Boolean)` and `==` would return different results when dealing with `Boolean` objects?

```
Boolean.TRUE == myBoolean;

Boolean.TRUE.equals(myBoolean);
```

I'm not thinking about primitive types here, just Boolean objects.

Comment: have you tried with multiple instances of `Boolean`?

Comment: `myBoolean1 == myBoolean2` where both equal true?

Comment: Here's why I asked the question: `Boolean a1 = true;
Boolean a2 = true;
System.out.println(a1 == a2);`. The output is "true"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
System.out.println(new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true));
System.out.println(new Boolean(true) == Boolean.TRUE);
```

(both print false, for [the same reason as any other type of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)).

Comment: why it print false? can you explain?

Comment: `new Boolean(true) == Boolean.TRUE` would showcase the issue even better.

Comment: its false because we are comparing objects with `==` sign?

Comment: @muneebShabbir The reason why it prints false is the same a for any other object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator

Comment: Thanks for this... I wasn't sure if there are only ever 2 Boolean objects and all references point to those objects but I guess not

Answer (score 3):

It would be dangerous to use `==` because `myBoolean` may not have originated from one of the constants, but have been constructed as `new Boolean(boolValue)`, in which case `==` would always result in `false`. You can use just

```
myBoolean.booleanValue()
```

with neither `==` nor `equals` involved, giving reliable results. If you must cater for `null`-values as well, then there's nothing better than your `equals` approach.

Comment: Though that would lead back to the primitive value.

Comment: @Aquillo You make it sound like that's a problem. Why would it be a problem? Note that the result of either of OP's expressions is the same primitive boolean.

Comment: To me it would be a possible solution instead of a problem. Though OP stated his question is not to discuss the processing of primitives.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik primitive values are a problem with tri-state booleans (true/false/null)

Comment: @Aquillo OP is only indicating that `myBoolean` is an object.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah... what's the shortest way to safely compare tri-state booleans?

Comment: @JanDvorak No, you're right: `TRUE.equals(myBoolean)` is the shortest way---though not to *compare* tri-state booleans, but to determine if *one* such value is `true`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik only if the left hand side is a constant or two-state boolean

Comment: @JanDvorak ...you mean, as in `TRUE.equals(myBoolean)`? :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah, that would work. But, what if you had two tristates you wanted to check for equality?

Comment: @JanDvorak Then you are in for a couple more characters of code :) `left == null? right == null : left.equals(right)`

Comment: In ruby, neither of `TrueClass`, `FalseClass` or `NilClass` have a public constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Boolean.TRUE == new Boolean(true)) {
    System.out.println("==");
}

if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(myBoolean)) {
    System.out.println("equals");
}
```

In this case first one is false. Only second if condition is true.

It Prints:

> equals

Answer (score 0):

`==` only works for primitive types
when you compare Objects you should always use `o.equls(Object ob)`

Comment: Except enums. You can use == for Enum objects because Java guaranteed it is singletone