# Justify this statement : if x and y are String objects and x == y is true, then x.equals(y) is also true, but the reverse is not necessarily true

Tags: java

If `x==y` is `true` so `y==x` should be `true` isn't that the case?

But I found this statement :

> Reverse is not necessary true

Please help me with this?

Comment: Where did you find this statement?

Comment: `x==y` is a query for the same object reference, assuming x and y are Java objects, while `x.equals(y)` just checks the content of two different objects - and here the content can be different for two objects of the same class.

Comment: Your title and the body of the question are two different questions. You're not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I am confused, Please answer the title question

Comment: @user3125031 "The reverse" meant here would be "if a.equals(b) is true for some String objects, then also a==b is true." and this would be **false**

Comment: @MarounMaroun http://www.scribd.com/doc/188530778/0073523399-Java pg 561

Answer (score 5):

If `x` and `y` are String objects and `x == y` is `true`, then `x.equals(y)` is also `true`.

**But**

If `x.equals(y)` is `true` then `x == y` may be `false`.

Consider the following example:

```
String x = "abc";
String y = new String("abc");
System.out.println(x == y); //false
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); //true
```

Comment: +1 but OP is asking about the reverse ie, if x==y is true then is it necessary that y==x also returns true! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi OP is confused. His title and his question are two different things.

Comment: Congratulations on 10k :)

Comment: Haha, thank you! It's like a X-mas present and I'm just exploring the moderator tools. :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi The "reverse" refers to the whole sentence, not to `x==y`

Comment: @Ingo But in his question he's telling that `x == y` doesn't necessary implies `y == x`.

Comment: @Ingo:- Ok my bad. I got it wrong. Got confused with this line `If x==y is true so y==x should be true isn't that the case?` P.S. Congrats kocko for 10k!

Comment: Thank you :) Next aim -> 100k :)

Comment: when will i get 10k..:P btw congrats kocko

Comment: @kocko:- All the best! Happy xmas! :)

Comment: @kocko Congo.. But can anyone differentiate between (x==y and s.equals(y));

Comment: @user3125031, Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator) one

Comment: Thank you all of you :)
P.S I just started java a week ago