# Entering into text field (Android)

Tags: android, text, field

I have a editText in my view.  Their is a else if statement connected to that editText.  When you type in a certain word some code will run.

But when i type in the keyword the code isn't running.  I think the problem is that their is a enter key.  I just type the word in, if i hit enter afterwards it just creates a new line, rather then entering the text.
here is the code from my else if

```
public void editText (String editText)
{
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if(editText=="closer")
    {
        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
//                image.setRotation(image.getRotation() + 1);
        image.requestLayout();
        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) image1.getLayoutParams()).topMargin -= 1;
//                image2.setRotation(image2.getRotation() + 1);
    }
```

Comment: we can surely help you but please show us what you have done..

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far OR clarify your question so we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: @lal . i just updated the question with the else if code.

Comment: when i type in, lets say 'closer', but it doesn't run when i type in it to the edittext... so i am guessing i need to hit enter after i type in the word in the edit text

Comment: Try changing `if(editText=="closer")` to `if(editText.equals("closer"))`

Comment: [Why` equals()` method when we have == operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator) **edit** and [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: it still didn't work @lal   Is their any thing else i can do?

Comment: Are you trying to check the string while typing in the edittext?

Comment: Where are you calling the `editText()` function?

Comment: public void editText (String editText)
{

Comment: @iIveTh3PaST That is the method declaration - where are you calling the method.

Comment: mainactity.java, right after the public void onCreate

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings, you should use .equals instead of == , so it should be

```
if(editText.equals("closer"))
```

Also, as i can see in the comments, you are just calling the method on your onCreate, so it is being called once, when the activity is created.
If you want to check it every time something is typed on the edit text, you should use a listener like this:

```
yourEditTextName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // this code will be called everytime the text changes
    editText(yourEditTextName.getText().toString());

  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
```

});