# Simple Array: Check to see if value matches

Tags: java, arrays

I am simply trying to see if the inputted value matches a value that is already in the array and if it does return "Valid".  I realize this is very simple but I cannot get this to work:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] accountNums = { "5658845", "8080152", "1005231", "4520125", "4562555",
                                 "6545231", "7895122", "5552012", "3852085", "8777541", 
                                 "5050552", "7576651", "8451277", "7881200", "1302850", 
                                 "1250255", "4581002" };

        String newAccount;
        String test = "Invalid";

        newAccount = keyboard.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < accountNums.length; i++)
        {        
            if(newAccount == accountNums[i])
            {
                test = "Valid";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

thank you for any assistance (and patience)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: Consider making `accountNums` a `HashSet`; it is faster to check if a value is in a `HashSet` than to loop over an `array`.

Answer (score 6):

Use equals method. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and) why to.

```
if (newAccount.equals(accountNums[i]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Jayamohan's answer is correct and working but I suggest working with integers rather than Strings. It is a more effective approach as CPUs handle numbers (integers) with a lot more ease than they handle Strings.

What has to be done in this case is change `newAccount` and `accountNums` to `int`s instead of `String`s and also remove all the quotation marks from the `accountNums` initialization. Instead of calling `keyboard.next()` you can call `keyboard.nextInt()`, which returns an integer. The if-statement is fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using an array?

```
List<String> accountNums = Arrays.asList( "5658845", "8080152", "1005231", "4520125", "4562555",
     "6545231", "7895122", "5552012", "3852085", "8777541", 
     "5050552", "7576651", "8451277", "7881200", "1302850", 
     "1250255", "4581002" );

String test = "Invalid";
```

Then you just need this (no loop):

```
if (accountNums.contains(newAccount)) {
    test = "Valid";
}
```

Plus, it's easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings with ==
You must use .equals()