# I am having trouble getting substring to work

Tags: java, pattern-matching, substring

This method is supposed to get the number of occurrences of a certain pattern and return the int value. I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Code

```
public int getCount(String pattern){
    int occerenceOfPattern = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= strand.length(); i++) {
        if (strand.substring(i, i + pattern.length()) == pattern) {
            occerenceOfPattern++;
        }
    }
    return occerenceOfPattern;
}
```

Comment: What is `strand` here?

Comment: strand is an encapsulated string where I am searching for occurrences of pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your condition check in loop and also add new check inside loop block:

```
public int getCount(String pattern){
    int occerenceOfPattern = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strand.length(); i++) { // Updated check
        if((i + pattern.length()) >= strand.length()) // New condition to avoid exception
            break;
        if (strand.substring(i, i + pattern.length()) == pattern) {
            occerenceOfPattern++;
        }
    }
    return occerenceOfPattern;
}
```

New added check can also be handled in loop condition itself.

Comment: Works, thanks! I just had to change the first if statement:  `if((i + pattern.length()) >= strand.length())` to just greater than because if the pattern is equal to the strand occerenceOfPattern should still equal 1.

Comment: You are right, condition `i < strand.length()` will never true, as the loop will break before this due to inside block `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
    i <= strand.length()
```

.length() returns the total length of the string and the indexes of the string start at 0. So if i is equal to the string length you will get an out of bounds. To fix this use:

```
    i <= strand.length() - 1
```

or

```
    i < strand.length()
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes when the index where you are pointing to is `null`(does not exist). Here the problem I see is in `strand.length()`.

`for (int i = 0; i < strand.length(); i++)`

This should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating too far on your `String`.

For `substring`, `charAt`, or any method that requires to you to use an exact numerical value to get at a character or a group of characters, the size of the `String` is defined as the result of the `length()` call minus 1.

It's like an array (since it is backed by a `char[]`):  `"cat"` has length 3, but it's zero based, so I can only go up to 2.

Change your condition to be strictly less-than, and not less-than or equal to.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getCount(String pattern){
    int occerenceOfPattern = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strand.length(); i++) {
        if (strand.substring(i, i + pattern.length()) .equals(pattern)) {
            occerenceOfPattern++;
        }
    }
    return occerenceOfPattern;
}
```

(changed `==` to `.equals`. for reason see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and))   Use `equalIgnoreCase` if it is case insensitive.

length() is already described in rest of the answers

== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.

[How to compare Strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
i <= strand.length() in your for loop is your problem...
```

length() returns the number of elements in an Array. Always remember that index starts from 0. So, if length is 5, you have 5 elements 0,1,2,3 and 4. So, you have to use `i<strand.length();`

You get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because element with index "length-1" is the last element and you are trying to access element with index="length".

Answer (score 0):

3 problems...

Change <= to < in your loop.

You also need to limit the right side of the substring to not be past the end of the string.

And you need to use .equals() not ==.

```
public int getCount(String pattern){
    int occerenceOfPattern = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strand.length(); i++) {
        if (strand.substring(i, Math.min(i + pattern.length(), strand.length())).equals(pattern)) {
            occerenceOfPattern++;
        }
    }
    return occerenceOfPattern;
}
```