# How do I make multiple OR's in an in an statement more concise in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an if statement along the lines of:

```
if (characterStrings[occupation] == "bar-owner" || characterStrings[occupation] == "barrista" || characterStrings[occupation] == "shop owner")
```

How can I make this and similar or statements more concise in java?

Thanks very much I havent be able to find a documentation of this anywhere,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
if (Arrays.asList("bar-owner", "barrista", "shop owner").contains(characterStrings[occupation]))
```

This will check if `characterStrings[occupation]` is any of `bar owner`, `barrista` or `shop owner`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [switch -case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of multiple **or(`||`)**

From [java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) onwards switch supports strings also

small example

```
switch(characterStrings[occupation])
{
case "bar-owner": //some codes for bar-owner
break;
case "barrista":// codes for barrista
break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion also very helpful although not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: @user2752347 I have given a small example,check this

Comment: This answers a totally different question. He's not trying to handle each case separately, rather all together, hence the if statement including all of them.

Comment: @leigero using multiple or statements decreases efficiency thats why java provides switch

Comment: He isn't doing if else. If you notice the question is asking about a single if statement with multiple arguments. Suppose he was trying to say "If object is a bar-owner, or a barrista, or a shop owner, then slap them in the face." Your switch case will have 3 "slap them in the face" commands which is hardly more efficient.

Comment: @leigero I gave a small example,In `switch(characterStrings[occupation])
{
case "bar-owner": 

case "barrista":
other case
}` OP no need to write mutiple times

Answer (score 1):

First, you should NOT compare strings using `==`.  It is *nearly always* a bug.  For example:

```
    if ("hello" == new String("hello")) {
        System.out.println("Something impossible just happened!!");
    }
```

(The only cases where it is not a bug involve comparison of String literals and/or manually "interned" String objects.  And even then, it is a rather dubious optimization because its correctness depends on you never using "normal" strings.)

---

In Java 6 and earlier there is no way do a sequence of String `equals` comparisons that is BOTH more concise than AND as efficient as the original version.

Using `Arrays.asList`, as in

```
  if (Arrays.asList("bar-owner", "barrista", 
                    "shop owner").contains(characterStrings[occupation])) {
      // statements
  }
```

is more concise, but it is also significantly less efficient:

- The `contains` call must internally iterate over the elements of the list object, testing each one with `equals`.
- The `asList` call involves allocating and initializing the `String[]` for the varargs argument, and allocating and initializing the `List` object returned by the call.  (You can potentially "hoist" this to improve performance, but that detracts from the conciseness ...)

In Java 7:

```
    switch (characterStrings[occupation]) {
    case "bar-owner": case "barrista": case "shop owner":
        // statements
        break;
    }
```

is more concise, and could also be more efficient.  It is plausible that the Java compiler(s) could turn that into a lookup in a hidden static `HashSet<String>` or the equivalent.  There is going to be a "break even" point where cost of a sequence of N `equals` tests is greater than the cost of a hash table lookup.

Comment: This was extremely useful nonetheless Stephen C. Thanks again @JQueryLearner

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check all those conditions, then you have to check all those conditions. However, a switch block is cleaner with many cases to check for.

Also note that you are comparing strings with `==`. Don't. Use the `equals()` method.

Comment: Thanks, pray tell: What is better about equals? Thanks again.

Comment: Look for the difference between == and equals, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643079/2968614

Comment: Try this and see what happens: `String foo = "foo";
  String foo2 = "fo";
  foo2 += "o";
  System.out.println(foo);
  System.out.println(foo2);
  System.out.println(foo == foo2);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing strings use `equals()` method instead of `==`.
you can use [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Thanks, pray tell: What is better about equals? Thanks again.

Comment: ==  compares memory addresses whereas  equals method compares the objects. @user2752347