# Is there ever a reason to use == over .equals besides speed?

Tags: java, equals

I was doing a little research on the difference between the two, and I noticed that .equals seems to simply be more reliable than ==. Is there a reason to use == over .equals other than the (I'm assuming) speed increase?

I'm doing this research because I'm doing a little work with Java. Would there be a more important distinction in usage when you consider other languages, like C# or C++? If so, could you tell me why?

EDIT: Maybe I should clarify. When I said that .equals is more reliable, I meant that I can't think of a comparison that .equals wouldn't be appropriate for, but it's easy to come up with situations in which you should avoid ==. Can anyone provide me with a rather specific example of when you'd use ==, but *not* .equals?

Comment: in what language(s) does `.equals` exist? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: There are rare cases (can't think of a quick example, though) where you want to be sure to have the *exact same* object vs one that looks the same.  Unlikely to be true for String, more likely for some other class.

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking that .equals exists in multiple languages?

Comment: You can use == to check if your String was ever changed from it's original state in code you can see my answer for a demonstration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [whats the difference between ".equals and =="](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I know the difference, I just don't know why you'd use one over the other. I was looking for a reason to ever use ==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a time to use `==` instead of `equals` method. Typically the equality method checks the usual output of the class. For example string containing the word "cat" so when you use the equality method that is what it checks. However a class is much more than just a single field, but many fields as well as an address in memory. When using `==` on a class it literally checks if it is pointing to the same instance in memory. Only with primitive types does `==` do what you think it does.

Here is a really cool experiment to demonstrate...

```
String a = "123";
String b = "123";
```

The compiler optimizes the strings to the same address and so == will return true. However change the value of b at run-time EVEN TO 123 and == will return false because now they have a different address in memory because the virtual machine is not smart enough or it would not be efficient to do these kind of optimizations at run-time.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
b = input.nextLine();
```

Even if you enter 123 it will cause the == to return false because now it created a new spot in memory.

Comment: I'm still kinda confused - does this answer give concrete use cases where `==` is preferred over `equals`?

Comment: @wlnirvana If you wanted to check if the object was occupying the same spot in memory.

Comment: But when does one want to check if the object was occupying the same spot in memory?

Comment: @wlnirvana probably never unless you are making something very low level and you want to make sure the object is using the same memory space but at this point you probably are not using Java anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There's a big difference when comparing String objects in Java. Using `equals()` will compare the contents of the strings and tell you the result.  Using `==` will compare the objects and tell you if the variables reference the same object.  If you use `==` then two strings that contain exactly the same characters will appear to be not-equal because they are different objects (ie, you could  modify one and the other would stay unchanged).  The use of `==` to compare `String` objects is a very common mistake.  `equals()` is the correct way to compare `String` contents.

Comment: I think I kinda understood this to begin with, but thanks for more clarification. Do you have any information on the rest of the question? I'm curious as to when you'd even use == in Java.

Comment: Usually if a class has an `equals()` method you should use it.  For primitive types (int, boolean) or to compare against `null` you should use `==`. For classes it may be useful to use `==` when you're doing introspection or other class level work where you're actually interested in finding out if two variables reference the same object.

Answer (score 3):

== checks for reference equality; .equals checks for value equality. So they're not really checking the same thing; == is testing whether two things are the same object, and .equals is checking whether or not they have the same value (which is why some operation has to be defined for .equals, and can be overridden).

Answer (score 2):

> I was doing a little research on the difference between the two, and I noticed that .equals seems to simply be more reliable than ==.

Then your research is inadequate and/or your understanding of what you have read is incorrect.

In reality, `==` and `equals` are testing different things.

- `obj == obj2` is testing whether `obj` and `obj2` are the same object reference.
- `obj.equals(obj2)` is testing whether `obj` and `obj2` are equals according to `obj`'s definition / notion of what equality means.  This *could* be the same as the first case.  But it *could* be something completely different.  It is entirely dependent on how the `equals` method is implemented ... for `obj`.  For instance it is *common* for the `equals` test to involve comparing the values of the fields of the respective objects.

To illustrate, if I use `==` to test a pair of strings, I am actually testing to see if they are the same `String` object.  But if I use `equals`, I am actually testing to see if the respective `String` objects consist of the same characters in the same order.  These are two different tests, and in a lot of cases they will give different answers.

> Is there a reason to use == over .equals other than the (I'm assuming) speed increase?

Yes.  They *mean* different things.  So you should *primarily* be choosing between `==` and `equals` based on the intended meaning of the test ... in the context that you are doing it.

> Can anyone provide me with a rather specific example of when you'd use ==, but not .equals?

It might happen in a case where you have mutable objects.  Sometimes you might need to compare them "by value".  Other times you need to know whether two objects are actually the same.  The latter might happen when you are traversing a graph of these objects, and you need to know if you have "been here before".

The problem is that any example is going to be a little artificial ... in the sense that it could probably be implemented other ways that are (arguably) better.

Comment: It's too bad that there's only one virtual `equals`/`hashCode` pair, since equivalence depends upon whether an object will ever change, and the holder of an object will often know more about that than the object itself will.  Having one method pair which would regard as equivalent only those things which will *always* be equivalent, and another which would regard as equivalent things which will be equivalent unless or until one of them is modified, could do a lot to resolve such issues.

Comment: The graph traversal example is really helpful. IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some primitive datatypes where .equals would not be supported because the datatype in question is technically not a class (such as primitive boolean or integer).

Aside from that, there are -- as you already figured out -- performance differences when using == compared with using .equals.

Having said that, the use of '==' instead of .equals is *usually* an error in Java, unless you are inside a .equals method.  '==' checks for equality of the references (think: equality of the pointers, if you are coming from a C/C++ world), and .equals invokes an equals method with semantics defined by the developer of the class.

Answer (score 1):

One example is IdentityHashMap, see API

*This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values). In other words, in an IdentityHashMap, two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==k2). (In normal Map implementations (like HashMap) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2)).)*

Answer (score 0):

`.equals()` isn't more reliable as far as I know. It just serves a very different yet commonly overlooked purpose. As mentioned above, `.equals()` compares values -- not references -- and is useful when comparing certain things such as strings. I would recommend using `==` instead of `.equals()`, unless you know that `.equals()` is explicitly required. This is not only because `==` is faster, but also because it is common practice*.

*I'm a little wary of calling it convention, but it's definitely common practice

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, == compares references while .equals compares values.
== is faster than .equals, but if more than one instance of an object can have the same value and you are comparing the values, you can't use == and expect it to be right. If the two objects are a different instance, but have the same value, == will return false.

That said, there are some immutable objects that implement "instance control".

They do this using a static factory method. The class will define a static Map of instances of all the objects of itself that have been created. The static factory method will instantiate an object with the parameters passed to it. But, before returning the object, it checks the Map to see if it has an object of the same value.

If it finds one that is equal, it returns the object in the Map that has the same value instead of the newly created object.

If it does not find an object that is equal, it adds the newly created object to the Map and returns the new object.

The advantage of this is that, for objects that implement instance control, it is safe to use == to check for value equality because there is no way that two objects with the same value will ever exist.

[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058) discusses instance control in Chapter 2.

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has classes called Interners that make it trivial for a class that wants to implement instance control to do so by storing objects of itself in the Interner construct.

Immutable objects that implement instance control like this should indicate that they do in their documentation. If they do, you know it is safe to use == to check for value equality. But, for any immutable objects that do not implement instance control, you should always use .equals to check for value equality.