# two equal array lists but java does not see equal

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, junit

Here I declare two array lists

```
ArrayList<Location> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Location>();
possibleMoves.add(new Location(0, 1));
possibleMoves.add(new Location(1, 0));

ArrayList<Location> possibleMoves1 = new ArrayList<Location>();
possibleMoves1.add(new Location(0, 1));
possibleMoves1.add(new Location(1, 0));
```

its obvious that those 2 array lists are the same, but when I run this check it always seems to fail.

```
if(possibleMoves == possibleMoves1){
  System.out.println("lol");
}
```

I have also tried this and it failed

```
assertTrue("Player 1 1st piece could play to the left and down!",
arrayListsEqual(possibleMoves, possibleMoves1));
```

this is the method of arrayListsEqual

```
private boolean arrayListsEqual(ArrayList<Location> a, ArrayList<Location> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    int size = a.size();
    boolean thisOneFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        thisOneFound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (a.get(i).equals(b.get(j))) {
                thisOneFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!thisOneFound) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In what library is `arrayListsEqual` defined?

Comment: @Duncan its given in a test file that is made by the professor of the course

Comment: @user3567826 Please show us the definition of `arrayListsEqual`.

Comment: @Duncan i added it to the post

Comment: @user3567826 Interesting - that equality method doesn't care about the order of items in the list. How strange.

Comment: @Duncan i have no idea how it is not working, this is getting quite frustrating :d

Comment: `Location` needs an `equals` method since you are using multiple instances of Location for the same position.

Answer (score 4):

2 issues:

1. The "Location" objects are different instances. so they are totally unrelated objects.
2. The list themselves are different instances.

first: you need to check equality with the "equals" method of the lists:

```
 list1.equals(list2).
```

also, you need to make sure you save the SAME object in those lists (by using the same instance) or to implement the "equals" and "hashmap" methods in the "Location" class.

once that is done it should work.

good luck :)

Comment: i understand this but unfortunately i can't modify this 

        assertTrue("Player 1 1st piece could play to the left and down!",
arrayListsEqual(possibleMoves, possibleMoves1));

its given in the test file that was created by the professor, so supposedly i should make this work with the assertListsEqual

Comment: @user3567826 In that case your only requirement is to implement `equals()` and `hashCode` in your `Location` class.

Comment: @Duncan you are right!! its stupid of me to miss this! thanks, i guess  when you stay awake for 2 days working you miss the small stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

Please read about the difference between `==`  and `equals`. `==` checks whether both References refer to the same instance whereas `equals` tests for equality. Have a look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare reference objects with == , ArrayList is not a primitive data type.