# Text doesn't change in variable after pressing button in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

For a little android project I'm making a loginscreen.
I have variables, but they stay empty once I fill them in and press the button.

these are my variables:

```
private EditText email;
private EditText wachtwoord;
private Button loginButton;
```

here I fill them:

```
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
        wachtwoord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wachtwoordInput);
        loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        
        }
}
```

and my method which always executes the catch code

```
    public void login(View view)
    {
        
        try {
        
        if(email.getText().toString() == "jolt_koens@hotmail.com" && wachtwoord.getText().toString() == "admin")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gelukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mislukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: use `.equals()` to compare strings `email.getText().toString().equals("jolt_koens@hotmail.com")`

Comment: I am bit confused why these guy's giving the answer one after other, when raghunandan is already written it in comment, And strange answer's is same as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if(email.getText().toString() == "jolt_koens@hotmail.com" && wachtwoord.getText().toString() == "admin")
```

to this:

```
if(email.getText().toString().equals("jolt_koens@hotmail.com") && wachtwoord.getText().toString().equals("admin"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare strings using either of these methods

method 1:

```
 if(((email.getText().toString().compareTo("jolt_koens@hotmail.com")==0) && (wachtwoord.getText().toString().compareTo("admin")==0))
 {
   do something
  }
```

method 2:

```
if(((email.getText().toString().equals("jolt_koens@hotmail.com") )&& (wachtwoord.getText().toString().equals("admin")))
    {
   do something
   }
```

Comment: i tried this code and my app keeps executing the catch code because the variables are empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void login(View view)
    {

        try {

        if(email.getText().toString() .equals ("jolt_koens@hotmail.com") && wachtwoord.getText().toString().equals( "admin"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gelukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mislukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Try the above code.  Use .equals() instead of ==
To understand the difference between the two read[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and).

Comment: I don't know how it happens but it still keeps executing the catch method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(email.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("jolt_koens@hotmail.com") && wachtwoord.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase ("admin"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gelukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mislukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```