# Eclipse - Java, casting from double to int

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, int, double

I just started using Eclipse and I'm quite new to Java. I have a block of code which won't compile because the random number I generated won't cast in to an integer. The error message reads "This method must return a result of type int" on line two in the following block of code.

```
public class passwordHelper {
    public int rNum(String nums, String lets){


        int z;


        if(nums == "yes" && lets == "yes"){
            z = (int)Math.random()*36;
            return z;

        } else if(nums == "yes"){
            z = (int)Math.random()*10;
            return z;   

        } else if(lets == "yes"){
            z = (int)Math.random()*26 + 10;
            return z;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the "(int)" function to cast my number to an integer but it sends me the same error message, I have also tried using other methods of casting, such as "Math.floor()", "Math.round()" and combinations of all the three. And if anyone wants to know this is part of a code to generate a random string of numbers and letters for the user.

//Thanks for any help

Comment: String comparison is done by equals method. try to change nums == "yes" to nums.equals("yes") and the others

Comment: I suppose you have reasons but you should really be using boolean here instead of Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a value in all branches, there are 3 possibilities:

1) Return an int in the else branch:

```
public int rNum(String nums, String lets){

    int z;

    if(nums == "yes" && lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*36;
        return z;

    } else if(nums == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*10;
        return z;   

    } else if(lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*26 + 10;
        return z;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
            return -1;
    }
}
```

2) Throw an unchecked exception

```
public int rNum(String nums, String lets){

    int z;

    if(nums == "yes" && lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*36;
        return z;

    } else if(nums == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*10;
        return z;   

    } else if(lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*26 + 10;
        return z;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
        throw new RuntimeException("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
    }
}
```

3) Throw a checked exception

```
public int rNum(String nums, String lets) throws Exception {

    int z;

    if(nums == "yes" && lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*36;
        return z;

    } else if(nums == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*10;
        return z;   

    } else if(lets == "yes"){
        z = (int)Math.random()*26 + 10;
        return z;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
        throw new Exception("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to use .equals() for String comparison.

Comment: Why? Is there a reason? Performance? IMHO it gets compiled into the same byte code anyways...

Comment: "==" does not compile into the same byte code as .equals() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and

Answer (score 1):

your method must return an int value but at your last else block you are not returning anything. return a default value there, for instance return 0 or throw an exception which says invalid input.

And also;

To compare two strings you must use its equals method.

change `nums == "yes"` to `"yes".equals(nums)`

and

`lets == "yes"` to `"yes".equals(lets)`

Comment: While definetly true, and will come up later - this is not the question, the comment was enough.

Comment: eagean will not be notified until you add "@name" in your comment. Usually you are always notified for your own question and answer when someone comment you, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Great thanks and I actually ended up hitting the second issue you brought up so you sorted that for me as well, can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public int rNum(String nums, String lets){

    int z;
    Random random = new Random();

    if(nums.equals("yes") && lets.equals("yes")){
        z = random.nextInt(36);// generates a random number from 0 to 36
        return z;

    } else if(nums.equals("yes")){
        z = random.nextInt(10);//generates a random number from 0 to 10
        return z;   

    } else if(lets.equals("yes")){
        z = random.nextInt(26 + 10);//generates a random number from 0 to 36
        return z;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. If you cast it to int, you'll obtain 0. You can multiply the double, and then add cast using parantheses.

**Alternative:**
You can use:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

and then

```
rand.nextInt(...);
```

---

P.S.:

- add a return statement (at the end)
- change String comparison to use "equals"

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a reference type and you cannot compare a reference type with comparative operators. i.e. You cannot use `==` here.
To compare Strings you can use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

`equalsIgnoreCase()` doesnot consider casing while comparing two strings, and I prefer this to use here. But here I modified your code by replacing `==` with `equals()`. If you do not want to consider casing i.e. want true for `yes` as well as `YES` here then use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead.

```
int z;
if(nums.equals("yes") && lets.equals("yes")){
    z = (int)Math.random()*36;
    return z;
} else if(nums.equals("yes")){
    z = (int)Math.random()*10;
    return z;   
} else if(lets.equals("yes")){
    z = (int)Math.random()*26 + 10;
    return z;
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you need either letters or numbers in your password.");
}
```