# Comparing linkedHashMap values to strings in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, linkedhashmap

My question: Why is linkedhashmap returning an object when I am expecting a string (perhaps my expectations are incorrect?), and how can I compare if a string value "line" contains the value of the linkedHashMap "sections"? I am defining the linked hash map as follows...

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, String> sections;
 sections = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Then, I have collected lines of text from a pdf. If certain conditions are met, II split the text on a white space putting the numerical value "#######" as the key and the rest of the line as the value...

```
 if (tocStartFound == true && tocEndFound == false) {
     if (line.matches("\\d{6}.+")){
     String lineSplit[] = line.split("\\s",2);
     sections.put(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1]);
 }
```

Now, when i ask if `line.contains(nextSection)` I am told an "object cannot be converted to a charSequence."

```
if (sectionStarted == true){
    Set set = sections.entrySet();
    Iterator iter = set.iterator();
    boolean foundName = false;
    Object nextSection;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        if (foundName == true){
            nextSection = me.getValue();
            nextSection = nextSection.toString();
            break;
        }
        if (sectionName == me.getValue()) {
            foundName = true;
        }
}

Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(".+((?i)end of section).+");
Matcher ma = pa.matcher(line);
if (ma.find() || line.contains(nextSection)){
    System.out.println("End of Section");
    sectionStarted = false;
}
```

I guess I thought by defining the map with `<string,string>`, i was enduring that the data would be typed as strings.  Best regards and thanks for the help...

Comment: How is `nextSection` declared? What type? Does the method `String#contains` expect that type?

Comment: It is declared directly above the while(iter.hasnext()) loop, in this example - as an object.  BUT, previously declared as a String im am told "object cannot be converted to a string" on the "nextSection = me.getValue();" statement. I assume because nextSection is identified as a string, but me.value() is an object?

Comment: I clearly see `Object nextSection;`. So what is the declared type of `nextSection`?

Comment: So yes, changing the declaration to a String solves one problem, but creates another - but both are related to type incompatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the official tutorial on Generics in Java. Read it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

---

You've used a parameterized type with `sections`, but stopped using it after

```
Set set = sections.entrySet();
Iterator iter = set.iterator();
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
```

[These are raw types and should rarely be used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) Parameterize them correctly (and change the type of `nextSection` to `String`) and you'll be fine with type checking.

```
Set<Entry<String, String>> set = sections.entrySet();       
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = set.iterator();
boolean foundName = false;
String nextSection;
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String,String> me = iter.next();
    if (foundName == true){
        nextSection = me.getValue();
        nextSection = nextSection.toString();
        break;
    }
```

[Then remember that you have to use `String#equals(Object)` to compare `String` values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

[You should avoid raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Also for more flexibility of code [prefer more general type for reference over precise one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). So instead of

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> sections;
sections = new LinkedHashMap();
```

use

```
Map<String, String> sections;
sections = new LinkedHashMap<>();// <> in short: represents 
                                 // generic type of reference
```

BTW you can rewrite above code in one line

```
Map<String, String> sections = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Now as said earlier you should avoid raw types, so instead of

```
Set set = sections.entrySet();
```

you need to specify what elements this Set should contain. In this case use

```
Set<Entry<String, String>> set = sections.entrySet();
```

Now I am not sure why you are using `Iterator` manually, but main purpose of existence `Iterable` interface which lets some classes return `Iterator` is to be used in enhanced-for-loop, so instead of

```
Iterator<Element> iter = someCollection.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Element element = iter.next();
    //...
}
```

you can simply use

```
for (Element element : someCollection){
    //...
}
```

which in your case would be

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> me : set){
    ...
}
```

Now since compiler knows that `Entry` is of type where key and value are Strings, it can assume that `me.getEntry()` will return String, so you no longer need to declare `nextSection` as `Object` and invoke `toString()` on it to get its String value, but you can simply use

```
String nextSection;
...
nextSection = me.getValue();
```

Because earlier `nextSection` was `Object` `line.contains(nextSection)` couldn't accept it as argument (Object reference can hold any kind of objects like Set, List, Car, Cow, or whatever you think of) because it expects `CharSequence` like `String`. Since now `nextSection` will be declared as `String` your problem will disappear.

Also you shouldn't compare content of Strings with `==` [because it compares references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and). You should use `equals` method like `someString.equals(someOtherString)`(more info here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)).

Last thing is matter of coding style. You should avoid

```
if (condition == true){...}
```

because it can easily be mistakenly written as

```
if (condition = true){...}//notice one `=` not `==`
```

and because `=` is assignment it will first assign `true` to condition which means that this `if` will always execute its code.
To avoid such problems simply write

```
if (condition){...}
```

and in case of negation instead of `if (foundName == false)` you can use

```
if (!condition){...}
```