# Wonderful string content check

Tags: android, string, validation, smsmanager, pdu

I'm using this code and it retrieve incoming message successfully:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Object[] object = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) object[0]);
String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody().trim();
```

The message is exactly equal to "test" and `message.length()` is equal to 4 (no hidden chars) but the bellow command returns false!

```
if (message == "test") ...
```

How to use **==** instead **equals()**?

Thanks...

Comment: Use `equals("test")` method, since you are comparing the reference

Comment: How can you use `==` for comparing string? Use `str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: `How to use == instead equals()?` In **no way**!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question reveals that the OP requires an even **minimal knowledge** of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use below:-

```
message.equals("test")
```

for more info read below question:-

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't want to use equals() in switch/case frequently, how to check it normally with == ?

Comment: @MohammadLotfi seriously how can you compare `Strings` with == ?

Comment: @MohammadLotfi `I don't want to use equals()` ... Then simply give up and  **don't compare strings**!! Since **there is no other way**.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
message.equals("test")
```

**“==”** operator is actually checking to see if the string objects (obj1 and obj2) refer to the exact same memory location.

But, the **equals()** method is actually meant to compare the **contents (values)** of 2 objects, and not their location in memory.

see [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and) for more details

Comment: @MohammadLotfi You simply **can't**