# Conversion of character to String not working

Tags: java

```
String s="rahul".substring(0, 1);
  s==Character.toString('r') //2nd
```

2nd evaluates to false but it should evaluate to true since i am converting 'r' to a String.
Why i am getting false as a result?

By doing this i am able to make the condition true

```
 //char s=name.charAt(0);
 // s=='r'
```

;

Comment: Definite duplicate. :)

Comment: s.equals(Character.toString('r')) will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as: 
 `s.equals(Character.toString('r')`. For more details [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643067/1623602)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing Strings with `==` you should use `equals()`.

```
String s="rahul".substring(0, 1);
System.out.println(s.equals(Character.toString('r')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals instead, see code below:

```
    //current code
    System.out.println(s==Character.toString('r')); 

    //change to be as follows
    s.equals( Character.toString('r'));
    System.out.println(s.equals( Character.toString('r')));
```