# Is there any difference between == null and .equals("null")?

Tags: java, string, equals

I am confused about the following code. Why does it compare with both `==` and `equals` method?

```
(validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType() == null || validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals("null"))
```

[What's the difference between equals() and ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between

```
validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType() == null
```

and

```
validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals("null")
```

?

Comment: This looks like a workaround for (or maybe part of) some really awkward code.

Comment: It prevents a NPE if `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` is `null`, otherwise you will call equals on a null reference.

Comment: Your question is very confusing... I don't see the relevance in linking the other question, or even the need for your first paragraph at all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType() == null` compares to `null` (i.e. checks if `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` is null). `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals("null")` compares `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` to a String whose value is `"null"`.

Note that first comparison must be done first, since if `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` is null, you can't call `equals` on it (since it will throw a `NullPointerException`). Since `||` is a short circuit operator, evaluating the first operand to true will prevent the second operand from being evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a massive difference...

`.equals()` calls the method which can theoretically be overridden and in the case of String compares the contents of the strings in memory, it checks if each variable contains the the same sequence of characters.

`==` checks if the variables point to the same location in memory.

In a lot of cases an `==` check on two String variables will evaluate to false, even if the Strings contain the same characters

In your particular case, one is actually checking the `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` method returns a null response (Nothing), by seeing if teh variable is not actually pointing at a memory location at all, and then if that is not the case it checks if it returns a String containing the character sequence `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType() == null
```

Check's if the reference returned by getBondTAFolderType() is `null`

```
validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals("null")
```

Checks if the string returned by getBondTAFolderType() is equals to the string "null". This is similar to

```
String nullString = "null";
validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals(nullString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType() == null` -> comparesto null .
`validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType().equals("null")`  -> if `validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType()` is null then you will get the NPE because you can't execute a method on null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is.

`null` is not technically a String;

`"null"` is a String.

If you want to compare to both cases, you'll probably need

```
String folderType = validFolderRow.getBondTAFolderType();
if(folderType != null && !"null".equals(folderType)) {
    ...
}
```

And there's of course also that `==` compares references, while `.equals()` compares content.