# '==' does not work while checking string values, but '.equals()'does. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;
public class RandomTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] alphabets={"a","b"};
    String [] cipher={"b","c"};
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter.");
                String word=input.nextLine();

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        if (word.equals(alphabets[i])){
            System.out.println("Preparing a cipher");
            System.out.println("Here is the cipher: "+cipher[i]);

            }
    }
}
}
```

This code above works perfectly fine, but instead of saying `(word.equals(alphabets[i]))`, if i put `word==alphabets[i]` it wouldn't work at all. While using the later, the program does not check if the input is equal to a value in the array. Why does this happen?

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: This may be better duplicate: [whats the difference between “.equals" and "==”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Answer (score 0):

`==` is an operator which compares the objects' locations in memory. `equals()` is a method defined in `Object` meant for comparing the actual content/values. By default, these two options behave similarly, but Java's `String` class overrides `equals()` when comparing strings.

In the future, please do research before asking questions. There is plenty of information to be found on the Internet.

Comment: "There is plenty of information to be found on the Internet"--my facepalm when I realize how many people don't know this