# ANTLRv4 String matching

Tags: java, string, antlr, antlr4

I have been working on something with ANTLRv4 this morning, and I have a need to take a certain string from the user, defined in the grammar as:

```
OP : 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

In a `{}` Java-thingy after a different definition, I need to compare the `OP` to another string. Currently, this is not working:

```
if ($string.text == "a") {
    //Do Something
}
```

where `string` is the name I attached to that specific instance of `OP`. How can I compare the text value of `string` to another string (`"a"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '==' operator will compare references in Java. To compare the value of the strings you have to use the equals() method.

Try this:

```
if ($string.text.equals("a")) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Read this for more info on the operators: [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do:

$string.text.equals("a")