# Java Buffered Reader string comparison gives wrong output

Tags: java

This is my Java code to read text from a text file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class checking {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

// Create a BufferedReader from a FileReader.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pw.txt"));

// Loop over lines in the file and print them.
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
    break;
    }

    System.out.println(line); // The output is abc
    if(line=="abc"){
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false"); //However it show false...
    }
}

// Close the BufferedReader.
reader.close();
}
}
```

Inside pw.txt, there is only one line which the only text in there was abc. 
I did an if statement to check if the line is equal to "abc" however the output was false... which I don't quite understand. 
Did I made any stupid mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `line.equals("abc")` instead of `line=="abc"`

Ref : [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Answer (score 1):

This is the huge mistake beginners to java makes please refer http://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java site on what is the difference between == and .equals() in java

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you compare 2 Strings:

```
if (line.equals("abc")) {
```