# How to test if a list of objects contains an object that contains a particular string as an attribute?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to test if a list of objects contains an object that contains a particular string as an attribute.

So here Is my list of objects

```
ArrayList<mObject> objectsList;
```

And here is my `mObject` class

```
public class mObject {

    String x = "True";

}
```

And here I try to make some kind of test

```
if(ObjectsList.contains(object.x == "True")){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I know the syntax is kind of ridiculous, but how can I make it technically correct?

Comment: With Java 8 you could use a Stream, but in the end, you will probably have to iterate over the list and return true, as soon as one object contains the desired value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For previuos versions of Java 8:

```
public class MObject {

    private String x = "True";

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

You can iterate over the list:

```
ArrayList<MObject> objectsList; //Init your object list.

for(MObject object : objectsList) {
    if(object.getX().equals("True")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, the solution was iterative. Was there another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for Java 8 you can use

```
objectsList.stream().anyMatch(myObject -> myObject.x.equals("True"));
```

please look at the code standards about naming variables (lowercase start and camel case) and classes (uppercase start)

PS: As your variable is a string with "True" value - are you sure not wanting to have a boolean?

Comment: it would be clearer for OP if you use the literals from the question (`...x.equals("True")`)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8:

```
List<mObject> list = ObjectsList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.x.equals( "True")).collect(Collectors.toList()).;
if (list.size() != 1) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

and, please, observe java naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

I override `equals()` method to be able to use `.contians()` because it comparing objects using `equals()`,as your List is `List<mObject>` (List of custom object) so i had to override the `.equals()` to be able to use `.contains()` probably

```
public class mObject {
    private String x = "True";
    public String getX(){
      return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x){
      this.x=x;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj == null) {
           return false;
       }
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
           return false;
       }
       final mObject other = (ttt) obj;
       if (!Objects.equals(this.x, other.x)) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```

To make your test :-

```
if(ObjectsList.contains(object) && object.getX().equals("True")){
   return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Please see the difference between `==` and `.equals()` when comparing string
from [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643079/5193194) link

Comment: I'm testing if ANY object in the object list contains a certain string attribute, not if a particular object exists in a list which contains a certain string attribute (the way your wrote it). The solution is iterative.