# Can't pass password validation Android

Tags: java, android

I just want to check if the given passwords are not equal to each other. So I had made this:

```
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmPassword = etConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

But somehow it doesn't work. I have logged it when I gave an input value "e" for both passwords.

Comment: check this information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this equals() method instead of != like this:

```
if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
```

With Strings you almost always want to use the equals method. In fact with Objects in general you do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `!=` , try to compare with `.equals()`

```
if (password.equals(confirmPassword) == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```