# Better way to check if an object is an instance of a class in Java

Tags: java, optimization

What is better to check if an object is an instance of a class?

```
object instanceof class
```

or

```
object == class.instance
```

Is it better to use first option where I need to import the class into another class to check if the object is an instance of the class, or to check if its equal to an object of the class initialized in its class?

I'm currently using `instanceof` method but I'm not sure if it's better to use that or maybe some other solutions.

Comment: You don't actually mean to write string literals, right?

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd example. Did you mean to write something like `object.getClass() == SomeClass.class`?

Comment: It's unclear what you actually mean by the second case. If you want to check if an object is an *instance of* a class, `object instanceof AClass` is obviously the way to do it.

Comment: Second case is checking if the object is equal to an object who is an instance of the class.

Comment: The second case is checking if an object is *identical* to an object which is an instance of a class, not equal - [`==` is not `equals`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and).

Comment: So if i have an indentical object, is it better to check if the first one is identical to second one, or to check if its an instance of a class. If i just want to confirm it's an instance of the class.

Comment: What do you think? Bonus question: do you think the difference matters on any practical level? Bonus question 2: how about measuring it?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "the difference", I mean the speed difference, not the fact that the two options may not even be functionally equivalent.

Comment: How do i measure that?

Comment: @ToniPejic Very good question. [Here's](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) a little intro and a fun tool to tinker with. It really is fun to test hypotheses like this, but we should always remember that even with the most carefully written test we may not be measuring what we think we are.

Comment: But what you'll find in this case is that the speed difference is so small that it really isn't worth worrying about. And of course your result will only be valid for that particular version of that particular VM on that particular machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj instanceof MyClass` is generally the preferred way, unless it *must* be a `MyClass` and not a subclass of `MyClass`, in which case `obj.getClass() == MyClass.class` is the check to use.

`obj == class.instance` makes no sense.
`obj == new MyClass()` would always return `false`, and makes no sense either.
`obj == otherObj` is an identity check of object instances, and is meaningless for checking if they are the same class, because unequal objects could still be of same class.

Comment: Thank you for explainig, by "obj == class.instance" i meant class.instance to be an object who is an instance of that class (an object of that class already defined in that class)

Answer (score 0):

Two options are not same. let me explain

first one is checking if the given instance 'object' is of type 'class' (or a subtype of 'class') . e.g

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

Object b = new B();

if( b instanceof A ){
 //will be true
}
```

Second option is not even valid.

using 'instanceof' is preferred way to find out if an object is instance of particular type.