# Why is my method not working with an input for a String?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Here is my method....

```
 void getMerchandise(String category){
         for(int i=0; i<merchandise.size(); i++){
             if(merchandise.get(i).getCategory()== category)
                 System.out.println("\n"+merchandise.get(i).toString()+ "\n");
         }
```

Okay, now if I call the method using...

```
  park1.getMerchandise("Hats");
```

It works just fine and prints all the items with Hats as the category.

However if I do....

```
     String z= input.next();
     park1.getMerchandise(z);
```

and then I type in the word Hats, it gives me nothing.  I have another method in which I do the exact same thing, and it works fine.  I have the scanner imported, and the scanner is static and is called input.  So there are no errors there.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the answer now.  Sorry I'm new and it bothers people.  You can stop down voting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals` to compare strings.

`if(merchandise.get(i).getCategory().equals(category))`

Comment: That's weird.  It does work now.  I don't understand why though.  It was still working before when I had it my way when I didn't put any input in.

Comment: @Nathan777 you'll need to know [the difference between “.equals” and “==”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Comment: I tried the .equals in another method instead of the ==, and it didn't work, but it was for a number of type long.