# Android :how to display all users in firebase database except one

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: image description]

Here is my Model. I want to display all users except "peter".
Here is my code:

```
  //iterating through all the values in database
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user= postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user.getUsername()!="peter"){
                users.add(user);}
            }
            //creating adapter
            adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), users);

            //adding adapter to recyclerview
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**problem**: my list still displays the user Peter!!

Comment: you can  not compare String with = use equals()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use equals method to compare 2 strings:

Replace: `if (user.getUsername() != "peter")`

With: `if (!"peter".equals(user.getUsername()))`

Method `equals( )` compares the characters inside a String object. Operator `==` compares two object references.

Comment: @kamenkov  thx sir

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings use `equals` and not `==`. Like this

```
          for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user= postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (!user.getUsername().equals("peter")){
                users.add(user);}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

== or != checks reference equality, not content equality. Use equals or equalsIgnoreCase
please use the search before posting
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : ref.getChildren()) {
        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        if (!user.getUsername().equals("peter)) { 
            list.add(user); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing there is an extra space there in word peter like this " peter" or "peter  " try to **trim** the string and also suggest you to use equalsIgnoreCase insted of equals

```
 if (!"peter".equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUsername().trim()))
```

tip- Never compare string using == oprater always use equal() or equalsIgnoreCase() for compare string in java Check Out [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643079/4741746)

Hope this help you