# Why is false being returned in this function

Tags: java

In my program below, I set the variable `th` as `true` in the second `if` statement.
I'm curious why it later returns as `false`.

```
public boolean nodeExist(TreeNode Tree, T value){

    boolean th = false;

    if(Tree.getValue()!= null){

        if(value == Tree.getValue()){

            th = true;

        }else{

            if(value.compareTo((T) Tree.getValue()) < 0){

                nodeExist(Tree.getLeft(), value);

            }else{

                nodeExist(Tree.getRight(), value);
            }

        }

    }else{

        th = false;

    }

    return th;

}
```

Comment: BTW: `if` is no function! It's an control flow statement.

Comment: It's not as bad as `if loop`. `:P`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably look at a recursive call which sets `th` to true. But when that call returns to its caller, *that* `th` is still at false, and that's then returned. You need to assign the recursive callee's result:

```
        if(value.compareTo((T) Tree.getValue()) < 0){

            th = nodeExist(Tree.getLeft(), value);

        }else{

            th = nodeExist(Tree.getRight(), value);
        }
```

Comment: Or, change the assignment to a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You already got your answer. In future, to prevent mistakes like this, it's better to just `return` the value right away if you can. IT'S OKAY to have multiple `return`; if used properly, it can read to more readable code.

```
public boolean nodeExist(TreeNode Tree, T value){
    if (Tree.getValue() == null) return false;

    if (value == Tree.getValue()) return true;

    if (value.compareTo((T) Tree.getValue()) < 0) {
       return nodeExist(Tree.getLeft(), value);
    } else {
       return nodeExist(Tree.getRight(), value);
    }
}
```

#### See also

- [Should a function have only one return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)

---

Additionally, I noticed that you used `==` instead of `equals` for object comparison (i.e. `T` can't be a primitive type). This is rarely correct; `equals` is almost always what is really intended.

#### See also

- [Difference Between Equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)

---

One more style advice, please follow naming convention for Java, where variable names start with lowercase letter, with upper case letter for internal words (so, `somethingLikeThis`).

Programming isn't about getting things right, it's also about getting things readable. Learn and adopt a good coding style, and follow established conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In the section in which you're doing your compareTo where the th value is not set.  If this conditional is met, th can never be set to true.