# Java Buffered Reader

Tags: java

```
 import java.io.*;

 public class TerminateWhen
 {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     String str = "";
     System.out.println("Type \"x\" to exit..");
     do {
       str = br.readLine();
       System.out.println(str);
       }
     while(str!="x");
   }
 }
```

the problem is even if  will type the "x", the loop will not exit..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `!str.equals("x")` !!!

Answer (score 5):

Beware "standard" comparison operators when you're working with strings.

```
str != "x"
```

compares the two references, not the string's contents. Use the "equals" method to compare the string contents.

Answer (score 1):

You must check for `equals()`