# A Question about JTextField in Java

Tags: java, string, object-identity

I met a small problem when running a Java class that I wrote, though the design is pretty straightforward. I've created a JPanel, and I've added four JTextFields onto it and I've attached a button to this JPanel, too. Then, I've associated an ActionListener to this button being pressed. The code is like:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
       if (imageIdField.getText() == "" && 
           captionField.getText() == "" &&
           creditField.getText() == "" &&
           titleField.getText()== "") 
           {
              mediaXML = "";                        
              results.clear();
              results.put("error1", "more");

           } 
           else
           { ....
           }
    }
```

The strange thing is after I've pressed the OK button, and I did input text in those four JTextFields, still it will fall in the IF branch as if I didn't input any text in any of these four fields.
I've been debugging this for a while, but no clue. Could anyone give me some hint like whether .getText() == "" is a valid way for testing no input?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned, using `==` is not correct. For readability, try:

```
field.getText().isEmpty()
```

or

```
field.getText().trim().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally a bad idea to use `==` on `String`s, or most other things. It checks that the objects are exactly the same instance, not that they have the same value. `"" != new String("")`.

```
field.getText().equals("")
```

Or possibly better:

```
field.getText().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getText().equals("")` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

Use == to check if it is the same object in memory, and .equals("YOUR STRING") to check if the content of the object is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Also, you might want to do something like this:

```
imageField.getText().trim().length() == 0  //The same for the others
```

or

```
imageField.getText().trim().isEmpty() //The same for the others
```

if you want to make sure that the user has actually written some characters instead of just white spaces.

Comment: it removes all white space at both ends of the string

Comment: Yeah, in most cases you want to avoid having the user provide a bunch of white spaces as input. For instance for user names, you might want to have alpha numeric characters instead of a bunch of white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`==` only checks whether the left hand side and the right hand side refer to the exact same instance of an object. And since `""` translates to something like `new String("")`, it will always return false, if you compare it with a string that already exists.

If you want to compare whether two instances of a class have the same state you need to use `equals()`. In your case `*.getText().equals("")`. A more elegant method would to use the `isEmpty()` method of the String class.