# Java null check why use == instead of .equals()

Tags: java, null

In Java I am told that when doing a null check one should use == instead of .equals(). What are the reasons for this?

Comment: The easiest thing is to try null checking with `equals()` and see. When you try it will instantly be obvious

Comment: By the way, a google search with keywords "java null check" (without quotes) gave me as one of the top hits [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t151631-stringobj-null-vs-stringobj-equals-null-for-null-check.html), which has the same info as the answers here.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

They're two completely different things. `==` compares the object reference, if any, contained by a variable. `.equals()` checks to see if two objects are *equal* according to their contract for what equality means. It's entirely possible for two distinct object instances to be "equal" according to their contract. And then there's the minor detail that since `equals` is a method, if you try to invoke it on a `null` reference, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

For instance:

```
class Foo {
    private int data;

    Foo(int d) {
        this.data = d;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
           return false;
        }
        return ((Foo)other).data == this.data;
    }

    /* In a real class, you'd override `hashCode` here as well */
}

Foo f1 = new Foo(5);
Foo f2 = new Foo(5);
System.out.println(f1 == f2);
// outputs false, they're distinct object instances

System.out.println(f1.equals(f2));
// outputs true, they're "equal" according to their definition

Foo f3 = null;
System.out.println(f3 == null);
// outputs true, `f3` doesn't have any object reference assigned to it

System.out.println(f3.equals(null));
// Throws a NullPointerException, you can't dereference `f3`, it doesn't refer to anything

System.out.println(f1.equals(f3));
// Outputs false, since `f1` is a valid instance but `f3` is null,
// so one of the first checks inside the `Foo#equals` method will
// disallow the equality because it sees that `other` == null
```

Comment: do you mean `public int data`?

Comment: @Xepoch: No, I don't generally create public fields (although it doesn't really matter for this example either way). Why?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder "They're two completely different things.." in general yes. However, the default implementation of both is the same, if my understanding is correct. Looking at the source code, .equals() basically does an == check. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java

Comment: @Ayush - That's the default in `Object`, yes. It's overridden by a large number of the JDK classes, though. But the point about isn't about implementation, it's about semantics. (Side note: JDK7 is very out of date.)

Comment: Right, that makes sense, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Wouldn't writing `null` create a new null value with a different reference? Why would the equality ever return `true`?

Comment: @RogerWang - Good question! The answer is that `null` isn't an object, it's an object *reference* (a blank one). It's the only object reference we can write literally in code. So `Object a = null; Object b = null;` means that `a == b` is true, because both variables contain the same object reference (the single universal blank one).

Answer (score 48):

In addition to the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501084/6276704):

Since Java 1.7, if you want to compare two Objects which might be null, I recommend this function:

```
Objects.equals(onePossibleNull, twoPossibleNull)
```

> java.util.Objects
>
> This class consists of static utility methods for operating on
>   objects. These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods
>   for computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an
>   object, and comparing two objects.
>
> Since:
>   1.7

Comment: Just to make it more visible for others (see chin90's answer or the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))): `Objects.equals(null, null)` will return `true` - keep that in mind.

Comment: Intellij always suggests to use `Object.equals()` instead, when I use `==` in my code.

Answer (score 45):

if you invoke `.equals()` on `null` you will get `NullPointerException`

So it is always advisble to check nullity before invoking method where ever it applies

```
if(str!=null && str.equals("hi")){
 //str contains hi
}
```

**Also See**

- [difference-between-equals-and == in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)

Comment: Your example is generally better written as `if ("hi".equals(str))`.

Comment: @user368186: the point isn't whether the equals method includes a null check.  If your object reference is null, then the call `someObject.equals(null)` will raise a `NullPointerException` without ever entering the equals method.

Comment: @ColinD  Agree just demonstrating here

Comment: It's always advisable to avoid nulls at all cost, so you don't need null checks at all ;).

Comment: You can always use 
`Objects.equals(a, b)`
It won't raise NullPointerException, but it still depends on the "equal" method of the "a" and "b"

Answer (score 30):

In Java 0 or null are simple types and not objects.

The method equals() is not built for simple types. Simple types can be matched with ==.

Comment: upvote for the actual answer that is most useful as opposed to the obvious "NullPointerException will be returned" herp derp answer.

Comment: For  “simple types” hope it’s understood that null is not a primitive type, rather it’s default value for object, and have some interesting facts: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-about-null-in-java/amp/

Comment: For the record, you can't have a primitive with a null value, so yes, OP wanted to check null safety of objects and not primitives.

Answer (score 6):

Object.equals is null safe, however be aware that if two objects are null, object.equals will return true so be sure to check that the objects you are comparing aren't null (or hold null values) before using object.equals for comparison.

```
String firstname = null;
String lastname = null;

if(Objects.equals(firstname, lastname)){
    System.out.println("equal!");
} else {
    System.out.println("not equal!");
}
```

Example snippet above will return equal!

Comment: As stated by the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) (it's always wise to read those): `Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned. ...` :)

Comment: I mean... if both are null, they are indeed equal... I think that should be obvious to anybody using `Objects.equals()`

Answer (score 5):

```
foo.equals(null)
```

What happens if foo is null?

You get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 4):

If an Object variable is null, one cannot call an equals() method upon it, thus an object reference check of null is proper.

Answer (score 2):

If you try calling equals on a null object reference, then you'll get a null pointer exception thrown.

Answer (score 2):

According to [sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html) it doesn't matter what to use for default method implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    return this == object;
}
```

But you can't be sure about `equals` in custom class.

Comment: It matters, since `equals` can only return `false` or cause a `NullPointerException` (or something different if the overriden `equals` method is nonsense).

Answer (score 2):

If we use=> .equals method

```
if(obj.equals(null))  

// Which mean null.equals(null) when obj will be null.
```

When your obj will be null it will throw Null Point Exception.

so we should use ==

```
if(obj == null)
```

it will compare the references.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example where `str != null` but `str.equals(null)` when using `org.json`

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{field :null}");
 Object field = jsonObj.get("field");
 System.out.println(field != null);        // => true
 System.out.println( field.equals(null)); //=> true
 System.out.println( field.getClass());  // => org.json.JSONObject$Null
```

**EDIT:**
here is the [org.json.JSONObject$Null](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/05074386d3582e9ea98148eaf6fd44eeaca964da/JSONObject.java#L108) class:

```
/**
 * JSONObject.NULL is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls null,
 * whilst Java's null is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls
 * undefined.
 */
private static final class Null {

    /**
     * A Null object is equal to the null value and to itself.
     *
     * @param object
     *            An object to test for nullness.
     * @return true if the object parameter is the JSONObject.NULL object or
     *         null.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return object == null || object == this;
    }  
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that `field.equals(null)` returns true. This breaks usual Java behaviour and is therefore confusing. It should only work for `field.equals("null")`, at least in my point of view. I don't know why the library developers thought, that this would be good to support.

Comment: Btw, your first sentence has a grammar issue and it is unclear what you mean with it. Do you mean "Here is an example where `str != null` and  `str.equals(null)` return `true` when using *org.json*."?

Comment: I think that's because the `jsonObject` contains the "field" key that's why `field` isn't null, it has a reference which contains the `json.org.JSONObject$Null`  object

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't treat `Null` like `null` and would use `"null"` instead. But I guess they did that to avoid requiring Strings. But even with that lib, `field.equals(null)` is still *almost* always an issue :P.

Answer (score 1):

Because equal is a function derived from Object class, this function compares items of the class. if you use it with null it will return false cause cause class content is not null. In addition == compares reference to an object.

Comment: Well, the result can only be `false` or `NullPointerException` (if `equals` is not overriden to something bad).

Answer (score 0):

So I never get confused and avoid problems with this solution:

```
if(str.trim().length() <=0 ) {
   // is null !
}
```

Comment: If str is null this will be an NPE

Comment: Additionally an _empty_ string (`""` having length 0) is something entirely different than a `null` reference (i.e. _no_ string).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this case last night.

I determine that simply that:

> Don't exist ***equals() method*** for **null**
>   
>  So, you can not **invoke** an inexistent method if you don't have
>   
>  -->>> That is reason for why we use **==** to check **null**

Answer (score 0):

You code breaks Demeter's law. That's why it's better to refactor the design itself. As a workaround, you can use Optional

```
   obj = Optional.ofNullable(object1)
    .map(o -> o.getIdObject11())
    .map(o -> o.getIdObject111())
    .map(o -> o.getDescription())
    .orElse("")
```

above is to check to hierarchy of a object so simply use

```
Optional.ofNullable(object1)
```

if you have only one object to check

Hope this helps !!!!

Answer (score -3):

You could always do

```
if (str == null || str.equals(null))
```

This will first check the object reference and then check the object itself providing the reference isnt null.

Comment: if (str == null || str.equals(null) || str.equals(""))

Comment: i used your answer and added a check for an empty string!  if im not mistaken, null and "" are not the same thing.

Comment: Is it not completely redundant to add a 2nd check for null?

Comment: @JustinRowe It is not only redundant, it is also _very_ wrong. Please, never do something like `x.equals(null)`.

Comment: @Tom, JustinRowe  please see my answer above why this isn't redundant nor complete garbage  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals/41079420#41079420

Comment: @dina: Your post refers to Object compare, not String compare. It is not applicable to this post (assuming that str is a String which seems to be a safe assumption...)