# Getting NullPointerException with equals

Tags: java, pointers, null, breakout

im having trouble with null pointer errors in java, im trying to make a breakout game and i know what the problem is its this.

```
    GObject collider = getElementAt( ballX, ballspeed);

    if(collider.equals(paddle) && collider){
        ballspeed = -ballspeed;
    }
```

When the if statement it null the program gets the error.

Ive try this too but no luck

```
    GObject collider = getElementAt( ballX, ballspeed);

    if(collider.equals(paddle) && collider != null){
        ballspeed = -ballspeed;
    }
```

Comment: It should be `collider != null && collider.equals(paddle)`

Comment: Nearly everyday same question is asked, i am not sure you query the old questions with java null pointer exception equals method or like that. You can check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals] for detail explanation.

Comment: Your bug involves more code than this. The main issue to answer is why does `getElementAt(...)` keep returning null? Is it supposed to return null? If not, you have to dig into this code to see why. Use a debugger or logger to check program state.

Answer (score 4):

Try other way:

```
if(collider != null && collider.equals(paddle) ){
        ballspeed = -ballspeed;
    }
```

Read more about [operators in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: You (OP) can search short circuiting to find out why the order matters btw.

Answer (score 1):

You must do the `null`-check before you try to call `equals(..)`.
The conditions are evaluated from left to right: if the first one is false, the others are not evaluated at all, because the `&&` cannot be true anymore independent what the other conditions are.

```
  if(collider != null && collider.equals(paddle)){
    ballspeed = -ballspeed;
  }
```

If you feel insecure about the evaluation order, you can also do the following:

```
  if(collider != null){
      if(collider.equals(paddle)){
          ballspeed = -ballspeed;
      }
  }
```

Comment: ive try that but then ballspeed = -ballspeed does nothing

Comment: Have you checked that both conditions are true? (e.g. by using a debugger or logging `collider` and `paddle`)

Comment: i just check with the debugger and collider != ( is false) and collider still gets the null pointer

Comment: and now i getting a error with the collider != null. the error is collider cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `collider` is declared directly in the line before the condition. If you use *eclipse*, try menu: *Project -> Clean* to force eclipse to build the new [eclipse sometimes get confused ;-) ].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. collider != ( is false)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at equals(Object)

Comment: `collider != ( is false) ` Do you mean `collider != null` is `false`? If yes, than the `equals` method is never called. I think you must show us your current code, I cannot find the error, without seeing the current source.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said :

```
if(collider != null && collider.equals(paddle) ) {
```

should do the trick. so an expression of this form:

```
if (condition1 && condition2)
```

Condition2 will be evaluation only if condition1 is true. In this case, if condition 1 is null, condition2 will not be evaluated and this would prevent null pointer exception.

Comment: if i do that and then run the debugger to the ballspeed = -ballspeed line. i get the following errors in the debugger.

Comment: "collider"  (pending) 
 collider cannot be resolved to a variable 
"collider != null"  (pending) 
 collider cannot be resolved to a variable 
"collider.equals(paddle)"  (pending) 
 collider cannot be resolved 
"private void checkForHit"  (pending) 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements 
"GObject collide...lX, ballspeed);"  (pending)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your second if statement to

`if(collider != null && collider.equals(paddle))`

If statements are evaluated left to right, if collider is null, the first statement will evaluate to false and the second statement won't be executed. Alternatively you could do something like

```
if(collider == null) {
    //do nothing or attempt to get non null collider
}
else if(collider.equals(paddle))
{
   ballspeed = -ballspeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(collider != null  &&  collider.equals(paddle) )
```

This should work.

Comment: hi i try that and nothing i used the debugger to find out whats going on and the collider.equals(paddle) is never true.