# NullPointerException when comparing with null values in java

Tags: java, exception, if-statement, null, nullpointerexception

```
if(status.equals(null))
{
  status="Pass";
}
```

from above code it throws `NullPointerException`, please give solution for comparing value with `null`.

Comment: Do you want to check for `null` or `"null"` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `"null"` is a string. You want to compare the reference to null. Do the following:

```
if(status == null){
  // code here
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I didnt know that @Maroun Maroun..Please Explain.

Comment: thats when you write null but if you write "null" isnt that a string?

Comment: Isnt that what my answer says?

Comment: You are **absolutely right**. I'm very sorry for the confusion. I misread what you wrote.

Comment: No problem. I got confused when you strongly suggested that. By the way the code in question has now changed.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `status` itself is `null`. So when you do:

```
status.equals("null")
```

You're actually doing:

```
null.equals("null")
```

Which causes NPE. You should do:

```
if(status == null) //Now you're checking if the reference is null
                   //So you'll never dereference a null pointer
```

You might find [this link](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/null.html) useful.

---

**Related topics**:

[What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)
[Java null check why use == instead of .equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that String is class in Java.So whenever you call a method with unitialized object (which is a null object) then it will throw `NullPointerException`.In your case, there is possibility that your `String status` is not initialized So you need to make it sure.
BTW you should check `null`  without using `equals()` method because it doesn't make sense that you are checking a null object's method for its null value.
You must do like this

```
if(status == null)
//Do something
```

only use equals method when you want to compare a String and at the stage where you are quiet sure that your String is initialized.Let say `String status = "";` is a intialized String and now it is not null.
**Just for the info**
 while using `equals()` , try to use it like `"anyValue".equals(status)` instead of `status.equals("anyValue")` because by using like `"anyValue".equals(status)`, it will be more safe in case of null string and you wont get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Better explained than other's.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(status.equals("null")) //Just checking if string content/value is same
{
status="Pass";
}
```

By this you are just checking if value(content) of status variable is "null" String or not. IF you want to do a null check you need to do the following

```
if(null == status)
{
status="Pass";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to make it null as "null"! in your case compiler consider it as string.

```
if(stringVariable!=null)
{
    //ur Code
}
```

(OR)

```
if(stringVariable.equals(null))
{
    //Ur code
}
```

In case if ur working with string array you can do it as following

```
if(stringArray.isEmpty())//checks length of String array 
{
//ur code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .equals with a null . Use :

```
if(status == null) {
//Do something 
}
```

This is exactly the reason why the HashMap cannot store more than one null values . Because it always compares the key with other valuues and if a null is inputted the second time , it throws NPE .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since `status` is `null`.

Comment: no..Maroun  solution works for me