# Alternative to object.equals(null) in java

Tags: java, syntax

Please help me with these java syntax issue.

I know obj.equals(null) is wrong, so whats the correct way to write an expression like

```
 if(!obj.equals(null)){
 some code    
}
```

I am confused between option 1

```
if(!(obj == null)){
some code
}
```

and the other option 2

```
if(obj != null){
some code
}
```

There's one more, for an expression like

```
    if(obj.equals(null) || obj2.equals(obj3))
```

am I correct if I write

```
if(obj == null || obj2.equals(obj3))
```

or should this be different ?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4501084/645270) some info

Comment: option 1 is  option 2. If `obj` is `null`, `obj.equals(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException`, and `obj == null` simply evalute to `true`.

Comment: Both options 1 and 2 work ok, 2 being more common. The last code line looks fine.

Comment: Seriously, you are wondering whether `!(A==B)` and `(A!=B)` are equivalent?

Comment: Don't do option 1. It's technically correct, but uuuugly. It's about as close to objectively wrong as an issue of style can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are logically equivalent, meaning they will resolve the same way:

```
if(!(obj == null)){
    //some code
}


if(obj != null){
   //some code
}
```

If the object is null, this will result in a null pointer exception:

```
if(obj.equals(null) || obj2.equals(obj3))
```

This say if an object is null or if obj2 equals obj3, then execute a block of code.

```
if(obj == null || obj2.equals(obj3))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are verifying whether the reference is null or not, then use this:

```
if(obj != null){
}
```

or

```
if(!(obj == null)){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Options 1 and 2 are logically equivalent. I'd prefer Option 2, it's more concise.

`if(obj == null || obj2.equals(obj3))` is best because you avoid the possibility of calling a function on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

thats the actual [Object#equals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) implementation. They all are logically equivalent.

Except that if calling Object `object` is null, `object.equals()` will throw an NPE.