# Difference between equals and == to compare with null?

Tags: java, object, operators, equals, record

I have two scenarios given below.

Case1:

```
if( folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord()
                   .getChecklistCode() != null)
```

Case2:

```
if(!folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord()
                   .getChecklistCode().equals(null))
```

Can anyone tell me if both approaches are the same or not?

Comment: duplicated so many times

Comment: @NimChimpsky This duplicate is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can never call the `.equals()` method on an object reference that is `null`.
It is a method, just like the rest, so if the object reference is truly `null` it will just throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to check if a reference is not pointing to any object, i.e. it is a `null` reference you must use the `==`.

The `equals()` method on the other hand is used if you want to compare the data contained in the object. If the class in question overrides the `equals()`, like for example `String` does, then it will compare the contents of the object, rather than just whether it is the same object reference.

If you see an object like a *box*. `==` is comparing whether it is the same *box* while `equals()` compares the contents of two *boxes*.

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* use

```
  myObject != null
```

because if `myObject` *is null*

```
  !myObject.equals(null); // <- Exception! null.equals(...); doesn't work!
  myObject != null;       // <- Quite OK
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 2 will not work.  If the result you want to compare is `null`, the call of the `equals(Object)` method will raise a `NullPointerException`.  So you have to use case 1.

Answer (score 1):

The results will be the same if Object returned by getChecklistCode() implements equals according to `Object.equals` contract which says `x.equals(null) should return false`

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator is used to compare 2 objects reference equality

`equals()` check the value of the objects are same

**Case 1**

```
if( folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord()
                   .getChecklistCode() != null)
```

it will check the object doesn't have any object reference assigned to it

**case 2**:

```
 if(!folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord()
                       .getChecklistCode().equals(null))
```

`equals` is a method, if you try to invoke it on a null reference, it will Throws a NullPointerException, you can't dereference object, it doesn't refer to anything

Comment: This is not the question as asked and even if it was, it would've been a wrong answer. It's the exact opposite.

Comment: The error still remains: `==` checks reference equality whereas `.equals()` check value equality. The reason why you should use reference equality is to avoid a NPE, as described in a few others above.

Comment: `==` check if two objects are the same, `equals()` compare two objects

Comment: @JeroenVannevel can you please check my edit answer

Comment: Honestly your answer is now just a combination of my words with yours and makes very little sense. I think it would be a good idea if you'd read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals) answer to understand the nuances.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel now it's better

Answer (score 0):

You can get an exception if you use **Case2**

If `folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord().getChecklistCode()` return `null`, then it'll throw an exception to use `equals`.

```
<Object> obj = folderProcessChecklistBean.getFolderProcessChecklistRecord().getChecklistCode();
if (obj!=null){...}
```