# android-if condition doesn't work

Tags: android, if-statement

I have an android application and I have two `EditText`s.

The user inputs 'distance' and 'time.

I made an `if` statement to show an error message if the user didn't filled one of the two inputs:

```
String strDistance,strTime;
strDistance=edtDistance.getText().toString();
strTime=edtTime.getText().toString();
if(strDistance==null||strTime==null){
    txtError.setText("Please insert the distance and time");
}
else{
    calculateLogic();
    app.setFare(fare);
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Fare.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works fine if I filled the two inputs.

But when I fill only one of them, the application stops working (I don't get my error message)...

Comment: check strDistance.equals(""), dont use strDistance == null. of course for two variable

Comment: better yet, use strDistance.trim().isEmpty();

Comment: yes you are right. with trim() is better

Comment: No, the `if` statement is not broken in Android nor Java... You question's title in kinda bad IMO...

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(strDistance) || TextUtils.isEmpty(strTime) ?

Comment: Java null check why use == instead of .equals(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this one:-

```
if(strDistance.equals("")||strTime.equals("") {
 txtError.setText("Please insert the distance and time");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 strDistance.gettext()
```

will never returns null.

```
 strDistance.isEmpty()
```

Use this

Comment: Even if `edittext.setText(null)`? I mean "edittext.gettext() will never returns null"

Comment: it will return text string or empty, but never null.

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming the result and using `String.isEmpty();` This will ensure the text has a length of at least some text.

The reason to use isEmpty() is because `EditText.getText()` will never return null in its current implementation.

```
...
strDistance=edtDistance.getText().toString().trim();
strTime=edtTime.getText().toString().trim();

if(strDistance.isEmpty() || strTime.isEmpty()){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...

String strDistance,strTime;
strDistance=edtDistance.getText().toString();
strTime=edtTime.getText().toString();
if(strDistance.trim().isEmpty || strTime.trim().isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"Please insert the distance and time",2000).show();
}
else{
    calculateLogic();
    app.setFare(fare);
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Fare.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```