# string.equals(null) vs string == null

Tags: nullpointerexception, convention

I've seen some of this answered for `PHP`, `SQL` and `C++`, but can't find by java. There is some convention or best practice with that?

I'm asking about **`null`** not `equals` vs `==`

```
if (myString != null && myString == null)
```

or

```
if (!myString.equals(null) && myString.equals(null))
```

Comment: Here is the answer I think:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals

Comment: it's about `null` not `equals` vs `==`

Comment: It is the answer for your null. Equals will throw a NullPointerException in your case.

Comment: if `myString == null`, `myString.equals(null)` throw null pointer ..

Comment: Because if it's `null`, it's like writing `null.equals(null)`.

Comment: `foo.equals(null)` has no point because you can't call any method from `null`. So if `foo` is `null` you will end up with calling `null.equals(null)` which throws NPE.

Comment: I don't understand. First one is contradictory, and second one has no sense. Since `myString` would be `null`, you can't apply `equals` to `null` object.

Comment: my bad, not a good question and not a good research....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mystring == null`, if mystring would actually be null it would throw an exception, because you are trying to access its `equals` method.

Comment: And if you don't want to care about checking null before check a string value , you can do `"astring".equals(myString)`

Comment: This answer gives good additional reasons why not to use .equals, even if OP is specifically not asking about it :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501084/3255525

Answer (score 1):

If `myString` is not null, `myString.equals(null)` is false [by definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). If it is null, it will throw `NullPointerException`.

If you want to check whether `myString` is null, you have to check it by `myString == null;`

Answer (score 0):

> if (!myString.equals(null) && myString.equals(null))

Would not work as you are attempting to call a method (`.equals`) on the the none-existent object `myString`.