# Java: can't properly implement custom Iterator

Tags: java

UPD: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is no help at all. My question is not about what is NullPointerException. I have asked with hope that someone will show me, what am I missing in in my Iterator class, so it gets a null refference. I suppose you should unmark my question so I can get an answer to my very question.

I decided to make my own implementation of one-way linked list without any java built-in classes or interfaces. At first, I created classes MyList and Nodes, and implemented some functionality for MyList, such as: adding new element to the end of the list, removing some element, checking, if the list contains some element, etc. It worked just well, you can see the whole project [here](https://github.com/komendacki/MyList).

After that I thought I'm gonna need the iterator to go through the list. So, i have writted this class:

```
public class Iterator<T> {
private Node currentValue;
private MyList list;

public Iterator(MyList list)
{
    this.list = list;
    this.currentValue = null;
}

public T next()
{
    if (!list.isEmpty())
    {
        if (currentValue == null) currentValue = list.head;
        else currentValue = currentValue.next;
        return (T) currentValue.value;
    }

    return null;

}

public boolean hasNext()
{
    if (currentValue.next.equals(null)) return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

I think the code of the Node would be useful here:

```
public class Node<T> {

public T value;
public Node next;

public Node(T value)
{
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Then, I've made a class for execution of the program:

```
public class ExecutiveClass {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyList<Integer> list = new MyList<Integer>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(60);

    System.out.println(list.containts(10));
    System.out.println(list.containts(50));

    Iterator iterator = new Iterator(list);

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }

}
}
```

And it seems like my Iterator doesn't work properly, because I've got this for output:

```
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
false
 at com.my.list.model.Iterator.hasNext(Iterator.java:40)
 at com.my.list.engine.ExecutiveClass.main(ExecutiveClass.java:24)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, how do I fix the Iterator, so it will work as expected?

Comment: You run your code with a Java debugger, and fix the problems as you encounter them.

Comment: `currentValue.next.equals(null)` is not how to check for null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals

Comment: mlk, thanks, but it wasn't the source of problem

Comment: Given that is [line 40](https://github.com/komendacki/MyList/blob/master/src/com/my/list/model/Iterator.java#L40) and it is line 40 that is being complained about in the exception I strongly suspect it is.

Comment: Anyway, I've already fixed it myself