# not equals not working in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I tried the following code :

```
if (!object.equals(null)) {
                object.setItem(object1.getTime());
}
```

Here, **object** and **object1** are objects of two classes.

The problem is that it enter into the statement for a **null** value.

Comment: Quoting javadoc of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-): *For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.* And of course, `! false` is always `true`, so the `if` expression is, *by definition*, always `true`, which means the **`if` block will always be executed**.

Comment: *"The problem is that it enter into the statement for a null value."* Don't see how it can do that, since the `object.equals(null)` expression will generate a `NullPointerException` if `object` is null, so the code inside the if block will never be reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For comparisons with null in Java, you use object != null

```
if(object != null){
  //
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501061/java-null-check-why-use-instead-of-equals for more info

Comment: why the above code doesn't work with objects.

Comment: Each object can define their own behavior for what ".equals()" will compare equality to.

Comment: But must always compare not equal to null.

Answer (score 1):

The `equals()` method in Java compares two objects equality according to the equals() method contract which you have to override or it follows the Object class equals() method contract.

In any case, equals() method compares two objects. null is not an object.
null is a reference type whose check should be done by using `object != null`.