# Break DO While Loop Java?

Tags: java

I'm new into JAVA and I'm not sure how to break a the DO WHILE loop that I use in my code below? I thought I could enter -1 to break or all other numbers to continue the loop.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Triangel {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int control = 1;

while (control == 1){

    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number or -1 to stop");

    if(value == "-1"){
         control = 0;
    }
System.out.println(value);
}

}
```

}

Comment: This is not a `DO... WHILE` loop, this is a `WHILE` loop. You break it by issuing `break;` anywhere inside the loop.

Comment: Triangle : http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/angel_vs_angle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `.equals()` instead of `==`, like so:

```
if (value.equals("-1")){
    control = 0;
}
```

When you use `==` you're checking for reference equality (i.e. is this the same  pointer), but when you use `.equals()` you're checking for value equality (i.e. do they point to the same thing).  Typically `.equals()` is the correct choice.

You can also use `break` to exit a loop, like so:

```
while( true ) {
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter a number or -1 to stop" );
    System.out.println( value );
    if ( "-1".equals(value) ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

- For more on `==` vs `.equals()` see [Difference Between Equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)

Comment: == compares an object for reference equality, that is, do they refer to the *exact* same object?  If I have a structure that holds an integer, and I say new Structure(4) == new Structure(4), this will be false because although I've initialized the structure's integer to 4 in both objects they are different objects.  However, if I overload equals (and hashcode, see the javadocs) properly, new Structure(4).equals(new Structure(4)) will print true - even though they're different objects, they are the same thing as per their equals contract.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `String.equals()` method when comparing strings. Your `value == "-1"` code is checking reference equality, not value equality

Answer (score 3):

You can use `break`:

```
while (true) {
    ...
    if ("-1".equals(value)) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do not compare strings using `==` but `.equals` instead.

Comment: oh sorry - didn't notice this was java, thought C#