# Java closing statements

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

Okay so my code works, however if the user correctly guesses "blue", the line prints "you got the right color!". Then the code should end. However, it brings up another a k.next(); line. How can I prevent this?
If you do not understand, here is the code.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BEassignment11
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
    String color;
    String again;
    
    do 
    {
      
      System.out.println ("Try to guess my favorite color!");
      color = k.next();
      
      if  (color.equalsIgnoreCase ("blue"))
      {    
        System.out.println ("You got the right color!");
        
      }
      
      else
      
        System.out.println ("That is not the right color. Would you like to try again? Yes/No"); 
        again = k.next();
    }
    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase ("yes"));
    
  }
}
```

Comment: just break out of the loop.by the way be consistent with your `{}` in if-else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break DO While Loop Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370174/break-do-while-loop-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just break out of the loop with the "break" statement like this:

```
if  (color.equalsIgnoreCase ("blue")){    
    System.out.println ("You got the right color!");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` following `System.out.println ("You got the right color!");` within `if` statement at `do..while` loop.

Or define a variable before `do..while` loop, for example `var boolFlag = false` set variable to `true` within `if` statement `boolFlag = true`, include `|| boolFlag === true` within `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println....` is part of the else clause. You seem to be surprised that the line

```
again = k.next();
```

still gets executed even when the user gets the color correct. I suggest you change the else code to the following:

```
if  (color.equalsIgnoreCase ("blue"))
      {    
        System.out.println ("You got the right color!");
        again = "No";
      }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("That is not the right color. Would you like to try again? Yes/No"); 
        again = k.next();
    }
```

That will automatically tell the program not to run again if the user guesses correctly and will only read the user's answer for trying again if they answer incorrectly.