# Java program for user to input a list of names and then "ZZZ" to stop. Count names, but don't count "ZZZ"

Tags: java, count

I am writing a program to get a user to enter a list of 10 names or to enter "ZZZ" when finished less than 10.  I need the program to count the names, but not the "ZZZ".  It is counting the "ZZZ".  How can I fix this?

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    names[n]= input.nextLine();           
    /*Count names, but don't count ZZZ*/
    count++;//???How do I do this???
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7370174/1707353

Comment: You probably want to actually first put `input.nextLine()` into its own string variable, and then _check_ what its value is before you decide to add it to `names`, either adding the value, or breaking out of your for loop.

Comment: Insert this just above `count++;`: `if(names[n].equals("ZZZ")) { names[n] = ""; break; }`

Comment: A better solution, though, is to not use a fixed array. Instead, use an `ArrayList<String> names` that you can append strings to, do `String name = input.nextLine()`, check what that `name` is, and if it equals `ZZZ`, break. If it's not, `names.add(name)` and keep going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This presumes you have a array or list to hold the names.

```java
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name = input.nextLine();
     if (name.equals("ZZZ")) {
          break;
     }
     count = n;    
    names.add(name);
}

System.out.println(names);
```

Comment: Clearly she has an array called `names` to hold the names as presented in the question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  Nope.  It is best to use the interface when assigning an implementation.  And the type qualifier is not required on the right hand side.

Comment: It is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name = input.nextLine();           
    /*Count names, but don't count ZZZ*/
    if(name.equals("ZZZ")) {
        break;
    }
    names[n] = name;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: But this won't finish on `zzz`, it'll just keep asking for names.

Comment: It now breaks on anything other than ZZZ

Comment: that update makes no sense. If the string is `zzz`, break. If it's not, add it to the names array and increment the counter.

Comment: You want to `break` before `count++`.

Comment: @chrisKatnic I don't think she wants `ZZZ` in the list.