# What's the difference in this condition : STRING.equals("myValue") vs STRING == "myValue"?

Tags: java

What's the difference in `STRING.equals("myValue")` vs `STRING == "myValue"`?

I first used `STRING == "myValue"` but my IDE recommends to switch to using `.equals()`.  Is there a specific benefit to doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The truly preferred method is probably `"myValue".equals(STRING)`, since it avoids the possibility of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: Check out [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7311504/544963).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311451/difference-between-equals-and-instanceof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: This question has been asked twice today already. It a regular asked and answered. I wish google wouldn't keep going down so people could just search for the answers. When google the answer to this it only found 14 million results, I expected more ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Using == only compares the reference values; the equals() function actually checks whether or not the string contents are identical.

```
String x = new String("foo");
String y = new String("foo");
System.out.println(x == y); // prints false
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); // prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `==` compares references, not values, while the `.equals()` does the value comparison.

[Further reference](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, STRING == "myValue" won't work, because it will attempt to compare the references to the strings, and not the strings themselves.

.equals() way is the correct way and will give you the response you want.

Comment: Because the categorical statement that "`STRING == "myValue"` won't work" is *false*. It does work in many cases (due to interning.)

Comment: It doesn't work for what the question is imply.  He won't get an error, but it will return false unless he is comparing the same string (and reference) to itself.  I clarify that it "won't work" because its comparing reference values.

Comment: @dlev  - Can you explain the interning a little? It would seem that this is a boundary case, is it so common?

Comment: @Adel This link explains it better than I could: http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/