# In java equal and == behaviour

Tags: java

Please can you explain the below behaviour.

```
public class EqAndRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 10;
        Integer j = 10;

        Double a = 10D;
        Double b = 10D;

        System.out.println(i.equals(j));
        System.out.println(i == j);


        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(a == b);


    }
}
```

Output on jdk 6

```
true
true
true
false
```

why a==b is false and i==j not false?

Comment: It's reference equality instead of value equality, with the `Integer` the constant was intern(ed) with the `Double` it wasn't. You should always prefer `.equals()` with `Object` types.

Comment: See [Is it ok to compare immutable objects in Java using == instead of equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970823/is-it-ok-to-compare-immutable-objects-in-java-using-instead-of-equals)

Comment: @Volune, The Double objects in the example are immutable.

Comment: [java: Integer equals vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the `Integer`s the following way then you will get the difference as @5gon12eder said

**The Integer s i and j are constructed (via auto boxing) from integer literals from the range –128 to 127 which are guaranteed to be pooled by the JVM so the same object (see flyweight pattern ) is used for them. Hence, they compare equal by object references.**

try this code to initialize your integers

```
    Integer i = new Integer(10);
    Integer j = new Integer(10);
```

Answer (score 19):

The [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)s `i` and `j` are constructed (via auto boxing) from integer literals from the range –128 to 127 and thus are guaranteed to be pooled by the JVM so the same object (see [*flyweight pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)) is used for them.  Hence, they compare identical by object references.

For the [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29)s `a` and `b` on the other hand, no such pooling guarantee exists and, in your case, you got two different objects that did not compare identical.

Using `==` to compare objects if you don't mean to check identity is to be considered suspect and should be avoided.  The `equals` methods of both types are overridden to compare the boxed values (as opposed to object identity) which is why they return `true` in both cases (and should be used).