# When three numbers out of four are the same

Tags: java, if-statement

I used random generator to generate four numbers, then I have to decide if **three of them are the same**.

What is wrong with the following code ?

```
if((r1= r2 =r3)|| (r1 = r2 = r4)|| (r1 = r3 =r4)|| (r2 = r3 =r4)) {
    System.out.println("Three of a kind.");
}
```

The error says cannot convert from `int` to `boolean`. Also, I thought it should be `==`, but `==` yields error while `=` doesn't.

Comment: `r1 = r2 = r3` makes `r1` and `r2` equal to `r3`. The comparison should run more like `r1 == r2 && r1 == r3` .. because that would mean `r2 == r3` by extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java equal and == behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081037/in-java-equal-and-behaviour)

Comment: nope, not a duplicate (of the previous comment)

Comment: Besides: consider using an array here to hold the values, instead of 4 distinct variables... As that makes your solution really hard to enhance.

Comment: "but == yields error while = doesn't" -- didn't you just say that you get an error "cannot convert `int` to `boolean` with `=` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the equality operator `==`, not the assignment operator `=`.

When you compare integers you do it like this:

```
if(int1 == int2) {
    // they are equal
}
```

If you want to test that 3 integers are equal, you could do it like this:

```
if(int1 == int2 && int2 == int3) {
    // all three integers are equal
}
```

See that we have used the logical AND operator `&&` to combine two boolean expressions so that both expressions must be equal for the `if` statement to evaluate to `true`.