# in which cases equals() is similar to ==?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between Equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)

in which cases `equals()` works exactly like `==` operator?

It seems that they both act similar for `primitive data types`. Are there any other cases in which both of them act equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` compares the bits of reference for `Object` type so if you have reference to same Object it would be the case

**For example**

`Integer` for value  -128 and 127 (inclusive) it caches (while autoboxing) the instance so it would be the case here for the mentioned range of value of `Integer`

Comment: unless you use `new Integer` to create those instances.

Comment: it doesn't have to be -128 to 127 exactly, depends on Integer class implementation.

Comment: @JIV I am talking about java.lang.Integer from sun JDK

Answer (score 3):

For primitive data types, there is no `equals()` (because they are not objects, and have no methods).

The default implementation (in class Object) for `equals()` just does object identity check (i.e. the same as `==`). So if a class does not override it, it will have the same result as `==`.

Comment: This is the only strictly accurate answer.  All other cases depend on the way that the objects are created / managed.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `==` will always compare references for objects, and the actual value for primitive types.

Note that an array of primitives like `int[]` is still an object!

Answer (score 1):

```
    String test1 ="test";
    String test2 = test1;
    System.out.println(test1 == test2);
    System.out.println(test1.equals(test2));
```

Both will print -

true

true

Comment: if you compare String I think is much better to compare using equal(). Isn't it?

Comment: If you want to compare values of two String objects then definitely we must use equal().

Answer (score 1):

In addition to primitives (which are a special case) `==` and `equals()` behave similarly for every case in which reference equality is the same as actual equality:

- Interned Strings
- Certain `Integer` references (normally between -128 and +127, but this is configurable, and it depends on how the instance was constructed)
- Singletons
- Instances of `Object` (and any other class that doesn't override `equals()`)

Obviously, when in doubt, use `equals()`

Comment: In the case of `Integer` references, it depends on *how* the reference was created; e.g. `new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Obviously. To be perfectly honest, the sometimes-interning of Integers isn't the best feature. I'd almost prefer if it only happened during auto-boxing.

Comment: And you can break the singleton-ness of a singleton if you play nasty tricks with reflection.

Comment: @Sean Reilly In addition to primitives (which are a special case) == and equals() behave similarly for every case.
-- primitive data types don't have equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` method evaluates on `hashCode` comparisons. While `==` compares objects by reference.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.