# String is not equal to string?

Tags: java, string

```
String[] letters  = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "L"};

Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = (inp.nextLine());
String[] cord = input.split("");

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    if(letters[x] == cord[1])
        System.out.println("Fk yeah!");
```

Why the *Fk yeah!* never happens if I input one of A-L letters?

Comment: Are you sure `cord` is actually just the letter and no whitespace?

Comment: could also be upper vs lowercase

Comment: Yes, I am sure 100%. No, they both uppercase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between .Equals and ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772953/what-is-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Comment: you should use `compareTo` instead of `==`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Strings are objects. The `==` compares objects by reference, not by their internal value.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Use [`String#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead to compare the value of two `String` objects.

   ```
   if (letters[x].equals(cord[1]))
   ```
2. Use `char` instead of `String`. It's a primitive, so `==` will work.

   ```
   char[] letters  = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L'};

   Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = (inp.nextLine());
   char[] cord = input.toCharArray();

   for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
       if (letters[x] == cord[1])
           System.out.println("Fk yeah!");
   ```

Comment: holy cow you have a lot of badges

Comment: @Code: It's nothing when compared to Jon Skeet.

Comment: well congrats either way :) I bow to you Sir

Comment: @BalusC - does the `#` notation in `String#equals()` mean its an instance method?

Comment: @Kublai: Nothing special. I tend much to use javadoc style to refer the classname/methodname in written text (as one would normally do in javadocs).

Answer (score 11):

To compare Strings for equality, don't use ==. The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Two strings may be different objects, but have the same value (have exactly the same characters in them). Use the .equals() method to compare strings for equality. Similarly, use the .compareTo() method to test for unequal comparisons. For example,

```
String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT
if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // CORRECT>
```