# "==" Operator Doesn't Behave Like Compiler-generated Equals() override for anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, anonymous-types

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode
>   methods on anonymous types are defined
>   in terms of the Equals and GetHashcode
>   of the properties, two instances of
>   the same anonymous type are equal only
>   if all their properties are equal.

However, the following code demonstrates the compiler generated implementation for `Equals()` isn't behaving as expected.:

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2009,1,1);
 DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 12,31);

 // months since year 0
 int startMonth = start.Date.Year * 12 + start.Date.Month - 1;
 int endMonth = end.Date.Year * 12 + end.Date.Month -1 ;

 // iterate through month-year pairs
 for (int i = startMonth; i <= endMonth ; i++)
 {
  var yearMonth = new { Year = (int)Math.Truncate(i/12d), Month = (i % 12) + 1};

  if (yearMonth.Year == 2009 &&  yearMonth.Month == 2)
   Console.WriteLine("BOOM");

  if (yearMonth == new{Year = 2009, Month = 2})
   Console.WriteLine("I'm never called!");

  Console.WriteLine(yearMonth);
 }
```

Am I missing something? I am looking at the generated MSIL but don't see an obvious error. Is there a way for MSIL level debugging (besides WinDbg maybe)? Am I overlooking something?

I have tested .NET 3.5 (VS 2008 SP1 compiler). For reference, here's the generated Equals method:

```
public override bool Equals(object value)
{
    var type = value as <>f__AnonymousType3<<Year>j__TPar, <Month>j__TPar>;
    return (((type != null) && EqualityComparer<<Year>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<Year>i__Field, type.<Year>i__Field)) && EqualityComparer<<Month>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<Month>i__Field, type.<Month>i__Field));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` is not `Equals()` - I believe that your code should work as expected when you do this:

```
if (yearMonth.Equals(new{Year = 2009, Month = 2}))
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-difference-between-and-equals).

Answer (score 6):

Lucero has it right, but I want to add an explanation of *why* that's right.

For reference types in .Net, the == operator is meant to indicate *reference* equality; do two variables refer to the exact same instance of an object?

The .Equals() method, on the other hand, is meant to indicate *value* equality; do the two (probably) different instances of an object have the same value, for some definition of "same" that you are normally allowed to provide for your types?

Comment: ...with the usual exception, the `string` type, which is also compared for value equality when using `==` (in contrast to Java) ;)

Comment: argh! (slapping my forehead) I forgot about that. OMG.