# ReferenceEquals(variable, null) is the same as variable == null?

Tags: c#, reference, null

Basically the title. I see a lot of the former in the code I'm working on and I was wondering why they didn't use the latter. Are there any differences between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869601/c-sharp-equals-referenceequals-and-operator

Comment: There are also cases where you really *need* to use `ReferenceEquals` like when you overload the `==` operator so you don't accidentally end up in infinite recursion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)

> Unlike the Equals method and the equality operator, the ReferenceEquals method cannot be overridden. Because of this, if you want to test two object references for equality and are unsure about the implementation of the Equals method, you can call the ReferenceEquals method. However, note that if objA and objB are value types, they are boxed before they are passed to the ReferenceEquals method.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. One can overload `operator ==`, so you basically can get it return e.g. `false` always. The recommended usage for this operator is to signify value equality, so (for correcftly implemented operator) basically check against `null` *may* return true if the object is semantically `null`.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx) for more details and some historical overview.

Another difference is that for value types `ReferenceEquals` doesn't make much sense: for example, any two "instances" of `int 0` have to be considered the same in any sane circumstances. (For purists: I put quotes because, strictly speaking, we cannot talk about instances of a value type.)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying "Not really." To "Are there any differences between the two?"

Comment: @James: the title asks "is the same?"

Comment: right, though the last statement asks "are there really any differences", I just wanted to make sure it was clear to those reading your answer which you were answering :-)

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of `ReferenceEquals()` is that the intention is much clearer, you are trying to determine if two references are equal, not if the contents of the objects referred to are equal.

It does this by checking for `operator ==` equality between the two references cast to `object` (since the params are both `object`), which eliminates any subclass `operator ==` overloads that might confuse the issue (like `string`'s).

So essentially, this:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
```

Is the same as this:

```
if (((object)x) == ((object)y))
```

Though the former is easier to read.

There are definitely times where it comes in handy, especially avoiding infinite recursion when you are overloading `operator ==` yourself:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo first, Foo second) 
    {
        // can't say if (first == second) here or infinite recursion...
        if (ReferenceEquals(first, second))
        {
            // if same object, obviously same...
            return true;
        }

        // etc.
    }
 }
```