# Strings with the same contents are not equal?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, equality

```
public string OpenDialogueFile(string dialogueName) {
    if(dialogues == null) {
        dialogues = Resources.LoadAll<TextAsset>("Dialogue");
    }
    var text = "";
    foreach(var ta in dialogues) {
        print(ta.name + ".." + dialogueName);
        if(ta.name == dialogueName) {
            print("Found");
            text = ta.text;
            break;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

This code should find a plain text file with the name requested and spit out the contents.

With the files "test1 and test2" in `Resources/Dialogue` and requesting test1, the output is

```
test1..test1
Found
```

When test2 is requested, however

```
test1..test2
test2..test2
```

The program claims that test2 is unequal to test2.

Both ta.name and dialogueName are strings, so it should be testing equality by content.

Is there something wrong with my equality operation?

Comment: Is `ta.name` declared as string?

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TextAsset-text.html)

Comment: Any whitespace at the end of either string?

Comment: What do you get for your output if you do `print("\"" + ta.name + ".." + dialogueName + "\"");`

Comment: What's the encoding? Are you sure you're only comparing ASCII to ASCII here and not something that looks like "test2"?

Comment: Where are the string coming from? Could they have been converted from a `byte[]` ?

Comment: Every time I've seen this, there's whitespace (or something nonprintable) somewhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# .Equals(), .ReferenceEquals() and == operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869601/c-sharp-equals-referenceequals-and-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning your strings from whitespaces before comparing them

```
var cleanDialogueName = dialogueName.Trim();
foreach(var ta in dialogues) 
{
    var cleanName = ta.name.Trim();

    print(cleanName + ".." + cleanDialogueName);
    if (cleanName == cleanDialogueName)
    {
        print("Found");
        text = ta.text;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: 2 problems with this. First it should be `char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)` and secondly, it's potentially dangerous as it's stripping ALL whitespace so `"abc def"` is equal to `"a bcdef  "`

Comment: Fixed the code. OP needs to tell us if there can be white spaces inside those strings

Comment: I'm not comfortable with stripping those out, I'd much rather go with trimming from the start/end like this `ta.name.Trim()`

Comment: Modified to use Trim(). Thanks @DavidG

Comment: This resolved it, any ideas on how that whitespace got in there? The file name has no whitespace in it and neither does the request.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, "test2" should equal to "test2". Convert the strings to char arrays with the string.ToCharArray() method to detect the problem. Check the number of characters and their value. Maybe it is an Encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the == Operator it is recommended to use the `.equals` method of the String class to compare Strings for equality.

For more inforation please refer to [the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Using .equals instead of == should resolve your problem without having to resort to crazy hackish workarounds