# Compare two strings in two different ways

Tags: c#, string

I've wrote this small program in C#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(("7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F" == "‎7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F").ToString());

    var a = "7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F";
    var b = "7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F";
    MessageBox.Show((a == b).ToString());

}
```

First messageBox shows "False" while Messagebox shows "True".

My question is: why can I not compare the two strings with the `==` operator?

Comment: Probably a copy&paste error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# .Equals(), .ReferenceEquals() and == operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869601/c-sharp-equals-referenceequals-and-operator)

Comment: The `==` operator works just fine for strings. It's your second string literal that contains an invisible character at position 0, so it differs from the first string.

Comment: Also `"7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F".Length == 40 && "‎7797302D875A8922EBFC7DECBD352FE88F35642F".Length == 41`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second string has invisible *Left-to-right mark* character as [`(U+200E)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm).

Looks like just another copy-paste issue.

[image]

Comment: It might be important to note that you actually can use  the `==` operator for strings.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Exactly. I didn't mentioned in my answer because this question already linked/closed as duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/q/3678792/447156 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/814878/447156 in comments section. Also he can check it from [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,673) as well about how `==` overloaded for strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some how I didn't think of that my self :D

Answer (score 3):

The difference isn't caused by the comparison, but your test string strings.

The second string of the first case starts with the invisible 0x200E, the unicode *left-to-right mark*.